# Excel Data Transformation

Tags: excel

I have data in the existing table as shown here and I want the my table look like the expected table after transformation.

Existing Table

[image]

Desired Table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You ***may*** use the below formula to ***accomplish*** the query, assuming you are using **O365**, and when writing this formula, you have enabled the **Office Insiders, Beta Channel Version** then,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(array,A3:A9,
Col,COUNTIF(A3:A9,A3:A9),
VSTACK(HSTACK($A$2,MAKEARRAY(1,MAX(Col),LAMBDA(r,c,$B$2&c))),
IFERROR(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A3:A9,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(array),MAX(Col),
LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(FILTER(B3:B9,array=INDEX(array,r)),c))))),"")))
```

---

Perhaps if you are using **Excel 2021/MS365**, then try the one below,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `D3`

```
=UNIQUE(A3:A9)
```

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B3:B9,D3=A3:A9))
```

---

If you are not using the above Excel Versions, then try the following

• Formula used in cell `D11`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$9,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$10:D10,$A$3:$A$9),0)),"")
```

For the above formula you need to fill down and may need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> based on your excel version.

• Formula used in cell `E11`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,
(ROW($B$3:$B$9)-ROW($B$3)+1)/($D11=$A$3:$A$9),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

And Fill Down & Fill Across!

---

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source (table name)
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"State", type text}, {"City", type text}}),

//Group by Staate
//  Extract each States cities as a delimited list
//  Add a Count aggregation so we know how many columns to create
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"State"}, {
        {"City", each Text.Combine([City],";"), type text},
        {"Count", each List.Count([City]), Int64.Type}}),

//Split the city column into the required number of columns
//Then delete the Count column
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "City", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.Max(#"Grouped Rows"[Count])),    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Count"}),
    
//Rename the city columns to replace the generated dot with a space, as you show in your output example
    renameList = List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"),1), each {_, Text.Replace(_,"."," ")}),
    #"Rename City Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns", renameList)


in
    #"Rename City Columns"
```

[image]