# how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length

Tags: excel

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

i would like to get table 2 from Table 1 in a quicker way. can people help? thanks

so far i have done pivot tables and manually copy and paste transpose, but this is really time consuming/

Comment: Look at the solutions in the query link: **[Excel Data Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72875639/excel-data-transformation)**

Answer (score 4):

Here, a solution that uses `DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern to generate each row. Check for example @JvdV's answer from this question: [How to split texts from dynamic range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852522/how-to-split-texts-from-dynamic-range) and a similar idea `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern to generate the columns for a given row. In cell `E2` put the following formula:

```
=LET(set, A2:B13, IDs, INDEX(set,,1), dates, INDEX(set,,2),
  HREDUCE, LAMBDA(id, arr, REDUCE(id, arr, LAMBDA(acc, x, HSTACK(acc, x)))),
  output, DROP(REDUCE("", UNIQUE(IDs), LAMBDA(ac, id, VSTACK(ac, LET(
    idDates, FILTER(dates, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(IDs, id))), HREDUCE(id, idDates)
  )))),1), IFERROR(VSTACK(HSTACK("ID", "Dates"), output), "")
)
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

### Update

As @JdvD pointed out in the comments section there is a shorted way:

```
=LET(set, A3:B13, title, A1:B1, IDs, INDEX(set,,1), dates, INDEX(set,,2),
  IFERROR(REDUCE(title, UNIQUE(IDs),LAMBDA(ac, id, 
    VSTACK(ac,HSTACK(id,TOROW(FILTER(dates,IDs=id)))))),"")
)
```

The main idea is to use the `title` as a way to initialize the `VSTACK` accumulator (no need to use `DROP`), and have all the dates for a given `id` all at once via the `FILTER` function. As a side note, it can be expressed in terms of the pattern we explained in the **Explanation** section (see below), as follow:

```
=LET(set, A3:B13, title, A1:B1, IDs, INDEX(set,,1), dates, INDEX(set,,2),
  HREDUCE, LAMBDA(id, HSTACK(id, TOROW(FILTER(dates,IDs=id)))),
  IFERROR(REDUCE(title, UNIQUE(IDs),LAMBDA(ac,id, VSTACK(ac, HREDUCE(id)))),"")
)
```

**Note**: Keeping the same name of the user `LAMBDA` function (`HREDUCE`) for sake of consistency with the **Explanation** section, but there is no need to use `REDUCE`. A more appropriate name would be `PIVOT_DATES`.

### Explanation

`HREDUCE` is a user `LAMBDA` function that implements the `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern. In order to generate all the columns for a given row, this is the pattern to follow:

```
DROP(REDUCE("", arr, LAMBDA(acc, x, HSTACK(acc, func))),,1)
```

It iterates over all elements of `arr` (`x`) and uses `HSTACK` to concatenate column by column on each iteration. `DROP` function is used to remove the first column, **if we don't have a valid value to initialize the first column (the accumulator, `acc`)**. The name `func` is just a symbolic representation of the calculation required to obtain the value to put on a given column. Usually, some variables are required to be defined, so quite often the `LET` function is used for that.

In our case we have a valid value to initialize the iteration process (no need to use `DROP` function), so this pattern can be implemented as follow via our user `LAMBDA` function `HREDUCE`:

```
LAMBDA(id, arr, REDUCE(id, arr, LAMBDA(acc, x, HSTACK(acc, x))))
```

In our case the initialization value will be each unique `id` value. The `func` will be just each element of `arr`, because we don't need to do any additional calculation to obtain the column value.

The previous process can be applied for a given row, but we need to create iteratively each row. In order to do that we use a `DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern, which is a similar idea:

```
DROP(REDUCE("", arr, LAMBDA(acc, x, VSTACK(acc, func))),1)
```

Now we append rows via `VSTACK`. For this case **we don't know how to initialize properly the accumulator (`acc`)**, so we need to use `DROP` to remove the first row. Now `fun` will be: `HREDUCE(id, idDates)`, i.e. the `LAMBDA` function we created before to generate all the dates columns for a given `id`. Now we use a `LET` function to name the selected dates for a given id (`idDates`).

At the beginning of each row (first column), we are going to have the unique IDs (`UNIQUE(IDs)`). To find the corresponding dates for each unique ID (`id`) we use the following:

```
FILTER(dates, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(IDs, id)))
```

and name the result `idDates`.

Finally, we build the output including the header. We pad non existing values with the empty string to avoid having `#NA` values. This is the default behavior of `V/HSTACK` functions. We use `IFERROR` function for that.

```
IFERROR(VSTACK(HSTACK("ID", "Dates"), output), "")
```

**Note**: Both patterns are very useful to avoid [Nested Array Error (#CALC!)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-calc-error-d6ee03c5-daf6-426a-8df5-4b284730ab1b) usually produced by some of the new Excel array functions, such as `BYROW`, `BYCOL`, `MAP` when using `TEXTSPLIT` for example. This is one of the effective ways to overcome it.

Comment: My two cents: `=IFERROR(REDUCE(A1:B1,UNIQUE(A2:A13),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(b,TOROW(FILTER(B2:B13,A2:A13=b)))))),"")`

Comment: JvdV good idea to use initialize the accumulator with the title and with `FILTER` you get all at once. Thanks

Comment: @JvdV I updated the answer with the simplification you proposed in your comment. I gave you credit for that.