# How to split a search string into parts, then check parts against a database

Tags: arrays, excel, string, formula, excel-365

Here's what I'm dealing with:

- We have a database of machines and their part lists are specified using strings. For example, one machine might be specified with the string `&XXX&YYY-ZZZ`, meaning the machine contains parts `XXX` and `YYY` and not `ZZZ`.
- We use `&XXX` to specify that a part exists in a machine, and `-XXX` to specify that a part does not exist in a machine.
- It's also possible that a part is not listed (i.e. not specified whether or not it exists in the machine). For example I might only have `&XXX&YYY` (`ZZZ` is not specified).
- Additionally, the codes can be in any order, for example I might have `&XXX&YYY-ZZZ` or `&XXX-ZZZ&YYY`.

In order to search for machines, I get a string like this: `&XXX-YYY/&YYY&ZZZ` (`/` is an `OR` operator), meaning "I want to find all machines that either a) contain `XXX` and do not contain `YYY`, or b) contain both `YYY` and `ZZZ`.

I'm having trouble parsing the string based on the variable ordering, possibility that parts may not be shown, and handling of the / operator. Note, we use Microsoft 365.

Looking for some suggestions!

When I search for `&XXX-YYY/&YYY&ZZZ`, I should return the following machines:

| Machine | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `&XXX-YYY&ZZZ` | `TRUE` (because `XXX` exists and `YYY` does not exist) |
| `&XXX-YYY-ZZZ` | `TRUE` (because `XXX` exists and `YYY` does not exist) |
| `&XXX&YYY&ZZZ` | `TRUE` (because `YYY` exists and `ZZZ` exists) |
| `&XXX&ZZZ` | `FALSE` (because `YYY` is specified in the search, but this machine doesn't specify it) |
| `&ZZZ&YYY` | `TRUE` (showing that parts can be in any order) |

Comment: it seems you want to define a parser in Excel and it is not intended for that, there are tools/languages more appropriate to build a such a parser. If it is something simple it can be done. For example, the tokens we can consider are only `XXX`, `YYY`, `ZZZ`, if not, is there any pattern to identify them?

Comment: I provided a solution based on my understanding of the problem to solve. The solution doesn't relay on token patterns (it can be any string prefixed by the operation specified), but rather on the operation type, to identify each element. Please check it and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in cell `C2` with the following formula:

```
=LET(query, A2, queries, TEXTSPLIT(query,, "/"), input, B2:B7, 
  qryNum, ROWS(queries),
  SPLIT, LAMBDA(txt,LET(str, SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(txt, "&",";1_"),
    "-",";0_"), TEXTSPLIT(str,,";",TRUE))),
  lkUps, DROP(REDUCE("", queries, LAMBDA(acc,qry, HSTACK(acc, SPLIT(qry)))),,1),
  MAP(input, LAMBDA(txt, LET(str, SPLIT(txt),
    out, REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(qryNum, 1), LAMBDA(acc,idx, 
    LET(cols, INDEX(lkUps,,idx), qry, FILTER(cols, cols<>""), 
      matches, SUM(N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(str, qry)))), 
      result, IF(ROWS(qry)=matches,1,0),IF(acc="", result, MAX(acc, result))
    ))), IF(out=1, TRUE, FALSE)
  )))
)
```

and here is the corresponding output:

[image: sample excel file]

**Assumptions**:

- String values (operation and part) should be unique, i.e. the case `&XXX-YYY&XXX` is not considered, because `&XXX` is duplicated.

### Explanation

The main idea is to transform the input information in a way we can do comparisons at array level via `XMATCH`. The first thing to do is to identify each `OR` condition in the search string because we need to test each one of them against the **Input** column. The name `queries` is an array with all the `OR` conditions.

We can transform the string inputs in a way we can split the string into an array. `SPLIT` is a user `LAMBDA` function that does that:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(txt, "&",";1_"),"-",";0_"), TEXTSPLIT(str,,";",TRUE)))
```

What it does is convert for example the input: `&XXX-YYY&ZZZ` into the following array:

```
1_XXX
0_YYY
1_ZZZ
```

We change the original operations `&,-` into `1,0` just for convenience, but you can keep the original operation value, it is **irrelevant** for the calculation. It is important to set the fourth `TEXTSPLIT` input argument to `TRUE` to ensure no empty rows are generated.

The name `lkUps` is an array with all the `OR` conditions organized by column for `query`. In the format we want, for example:

```
1_XXX   1_YYY
0_YYY   1_ZZZ
```

**Note**: For creating `lkUps` we use the pattern: `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK`, for more information about it, check the answer to the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) provided by @DavidLeal.

Now we have all the elements we need to build the recurrence. We use `MAP` to iterate over all **Input** column values. For each element (`txt`) we transform it to the format of our convenience via `SPLIT` user `LAMBDA` function and name it `str`.

We use `REDUCE` function inside `MAP` to iterate over all columns of `lkUps` to check against `str`. We use `SEQUENCE(qryNum, 1)` as input of `REDUCE` to be able to iterate over each `lkUps` column (`qry`).

Now we are going to use the above variables in `XMATCH` and name the variable `matches` as follows:

```
SUM(N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(str, qry))))
```

If all values from `qry` were found in `str` then we have a match. If that is the case the item of the `SUM` will be `1`, otherwise `0`. Therefore the `SUM` for the match case should be of the same size as `qry`.

Because we include in the `XMATCH` both parts and operations (`1,0`), we ensure that not just the same parts are found, but also their corresponding operations are the same. The order of the parts is not relevant, `XMATCH` ensures it.

The `REDUCE` recurrence keeps the maximum value from the previous iteration (previous `OR` condition). We just need at least one match among all `OR` conditions. Therefore once we finish all the recurrence, if the result value of `REDUCE` is `1` at least one match was found. Finally, we transform the result into a `TRUE/FALSE`.

**Note**: For a large list of operations instead of using the above approach of two `SUBSTITUTE` calls. The `SPLIT` function can be defined as follow:

```
LAMBDA(txt,tks, LET(seq, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(tks),1),
  out, REDUCE("", seq, LAMBDA(acc,idx, LET(str, IF(acc="", txt, acc),
    SUBSTITUTE(str, INDEX(tks,1,idx), INDEX(tks,2,idx))))),
  TEXTSPLIT(out,,";",TRUE)))
```

and the input `tks` (tokens) can be defined as follow: `{"&","-";"1_", "0_"}`, i.e. in the first row old values and in the second row the new values.