# Sort data contained in blocks in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, data-manipulation

I have a large amount of reference data in excel, which I am trying to manipulate in a variety of ways. I'm having some problems with the way it is structured and sorting into a more manageable format.

Problem number 1:
I have three columns. Column A contains first a date, and then a designator of high or low. Column B contains times, Column C contains heights.

I would like to sort the data by column B (easy enough) EXCEPT I would like the date headings in Column A preserved. It's almost as though I have 365 tables, each with between 3 and 5 pieces of data - I'm looking to sort the 3 - 5 pieces of data within each date only.

This is what I have currently:

[image: excel data in 3 columns]

There's no issue with me taking the data and manipulating it some other way first - this is ultimately around me being able to take a batch of data (5x different reference points, each for 365 days) and develop a process to sanitise it and get it displayed in time order, as well as being able to get it into a usable format for problem 2 (I need to adjust some other data points by the sorted data once I have it).

This is what I would like it to look like (I manually went through each of these blocks and sorted them):

[image]

Comment: What about using a Pivot table for that?

Comment: you mentioned you want the data sorted by Column C, but the sample output doesn't seem to be sorted by this column. Would you clarify that? Thanks

Comment: Thanks David - for a pivot table I would pivot it, then sort it?

You're correct on the column c issue - that should have read column b. It needs to be sorted by column b.

Comment: A pivot table doesn't seem to work - because it's seeing the date as a 'heading' for column A, and thus I'd need to put headings on to columns b and c somehow.

Comment: thanks, yes the output you need is similar to a Pivot table, but it is true that your **input is not in the structure a Pivot expects**. So maybe use Power Query to accommodate the result in the way you wanted.

Comment: Thanks David. Any pointers on how to get going with a Power Query much appreciated - I looked earlier and the issue seemed to be that I couldn't select my data as an input. I might try saving it as a separate file to work with?

Comment: add a column for date on each record. then you simply sort by both columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do it in Excel as follows in cell `E2`:

```
=LET(rng, A1:C11, set, FILTER(rng, (INDEX(rng,,1) <>"")),
  dates, SCAN("", INDEX(set,,1), LAMBDA(acc, item, IF(ISNUMBER(item), item, acc))),
  in, FILTER(HSTACK(dates, set), INDEX(set,,2)<>""), inDates, INDEX(in,,1),
  out, REDUCE("", UNIQUE(inDates), LAMBDA(acc, date,
    LET(sorted, VSTACK(date, DROP(SORT(FILTER(in, inDates = date),3),,1), {"","",""}),
    VSTACK(acc, sorted)
  ))), IFERROR(DROP(DROP(out,1),-1),"")
)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

You can avoid the clean-up process except for removing the last row as follow:

```
=LET(rng, A1:C11, set, FILTER(rng, (INDEX(rng,,1) <>"")),
  dates, SCAN("", INDEX(set,,1), LAMBDA(acc, item, IF(ISNUMBER(item), item, acc))),
  in, FILTER(HSTACK(dates, set), INDEX(set,,2)<>""), inDates, INDEX(in,,1),
  out, REDUCE("", UNIQUE(inDates), LAMBDA(acc, date,
    LET(sorted, VSTACK(HSTACK(date,"",""), DROP(SORT(FILTER(in, inDates = date),3),,1), 
      {"","",""}), IF(MAX(LEN(acc))=0, sorted, VSTACK(acc, sorted))
  ))), DROP(out, -1)
)
```

### Explanation

Basically is to carry out the manual steps but using excel functions. The name `set`, is the same as the input data (`rng`) but we removed the empty rows. The name `dates`, is a column with the same size as `rng`, repeating all the dates. The condition in the `SCAN` function to identify a new date is `ISNUMBER` because dates are stored in Excel as whole numbers. The name `in` has the data in the format we want for doing the sorting and filter by date removing the date header and adding as the first column the `dates`.

Now we use `DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern (check the answer to the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) provided by David Leal) to append each sorted data for a given unique `date`. We add the `date` as the first row, then sorted data, and finally an empty row to separate each group of data. Finally, we do a clean-up via `IFERROR/DROP` to remove the `#N/A` values and the first and the last empty row.

Comment: Superb. That does exactly what I wanted. Very very many thanks.

Comment: a whole new level of excel understanding.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert just taking advantage of the [new excel functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-new-text-and-array-functions/ba-p/3186066)

Comment: @DavidLeal can I use the same sort of method/incorporate into the process the adding of the 'date' into each of the 'times'? Because they originated from plain text, the date for all the cells in column B is 00/01/1900. It would help on the later data use if I could combine them with the actual date (and also if I did that separately, it would mean they sorted logically anyway).

Comment: yes, you can try the following: `=LET(rng, A1:C11, set, FILTER(rng, (INDEX(rng,,1) <>"")), dates, SCAN("", INDEX(set,,1), LAMBDA(acc,item, IF(ISNUMBER(item), item, acc))), in, FILTER(HSTACK(dates, set), INDEX(set,,2)<>""), inDates, INDEX(in,,1), out, REDUCE("", UNIQUE(inDates), LAMBDA(acc,date, LET(sorted, DROP(SORT(FILTER(in, inDates = date),3),,1), addDateInfo, HSTACK(INDEX(sorted,,1), INDEX(sorted,,2)+ date, INDEX(sorted,,3)), blockInfo, VSTACK(HSTACK(date,"",""), addDateInfo, {"","",""}), IF(MAX(LEN(acc))=0, blockInfo, VSTACK(acc, blockInfo)) ))), DROP(out, -1) )`

Comment: Words cannot express how grateful I am @DavidLeal. That has just made a really laborious task 100000 simpler. Works like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome @JamesDavies, today I was helping you in the future you can help others, in the same way, other people from this community helped me a lot in the past. I am glad it worked.