# Convert cells to table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this spreadsheet:

```
Cell 1A: key a: 111; key b:Abc ;key c: xyz
Cell 1B: key c: 55t; key b:mmm ;key a: 123
```

Need help or pointers to find a way to build from it table on another sheet that looks like this:

```
key a | key b | key c
 111  |   Abc | xyz
 123  | mmm   | 55t
```

Is that doable with no code, just configuration?

Comment: Do you have Excel O365?  And are you doing this one-time, as a data cleanup, or is this something that needs to be dynamic as data is continually added?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming per tag listed there is no excel version constraint, you can use the following formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(cols, INDEX(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,":",";")),1,), n, COLUMNS(cols),
  REDUCE(cols, A1:A2, LAMBDA(ac, a, LET(arr, TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(a,":",";")), 
   aCols, INDEX(arr,1,), by_arr, XLOOKUP(aCols, cols, SEQUENCE(1,n)),
    VSTACK(ac, SORTBY(INDEX(arr,2,), by_arr))))))
```

Here is the output:

[image: excel output]

### Explanation

We use `TEXTSPLIT` to convert to an array the cell information. For example for the first cell, the following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,":",";"))
```

produces the following output:

```
key a    key b  key c
111      Abc    xyz
```

Via `INDEX` function we get the first row of previous array and name it `cols`. It represents the column names. Since for the following input rows the information can appear in different order, we use `cols` as a reference to find the permutation required on each iteration to get the information in the correct order. We use for that `SORTBY` function.

We use `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern. Check for example: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) to add on each iteration a new row via `VSTACK` with the values in the correct order.

On each iteration (`a`) for the input range `A1:A2` we convert the information into 2D array (`arr`), where the first row is the header (`aCol`) and the second row the corresponding values (`INDEX(arr,2,)`).

The output of `XLOOKUP` (`by_arr`) has the corresponding permutation of the columns (`aCol`) with the respect to the first column `cols`. Then finally `VSTACK` adds on each iteration the values in the correct order.