# EXCEL - Dual VLOOKUP and Interpolation

Tags: excel, interpolation, vlookup

I have a table on Excel with data as the following:

[image]

Meaning, I have different **JPH** based on the **%SMALL** unit and the number of active stations.

I need to create a matrix like the following (with **%SMALL** on horizontal and **STATIONS** on vertical axes):

[image]

And the formula for each cell should:

- Take the input of Stations (column "B")
- Check, for that specific Stations number, the amount of data on the other table (like make a filter on **STATIONS** for the specific number)
- Perform an *VLOOKUP* for checking the **JPH** based on the **%SMALL** value on row 2
- Interpolate for the exact **JPH** value, if not found on table

For now, I was able to create the last part (the *VLOOKUP* and the interpolation), with the following:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2;'EARLY-STATIONS'!$F:$H;3;FALSE);AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDEX('EARLY-STATIONS'!$H:$H;MATCH(C2;'EARLY-STATIONS'!$F:$F;1));0;0;2;1)))
```

[image]

The problem I'm facing is than with this, the calculation is not checking the number of stations, so the Iteration is not accurate.

Unfortunately I **cannot use VBA macros** to solve this.

Any clue?

Comment: Miguel, I think it is doable, I have one question, what do you mean by interpolation? My understanding is that you look for the station number, then you find the %SMALL and enter the corresponding JPH value, but the interpolation confused me. Thanks

Comment: I mean than, if for example there is 34% of SMALL and 39% of SMALL for a specific number of stations, on 35-36-37-38% the code should find the JPH doing a progression

Comment: Understood, but you are assuming there are more than one value to extrapolate from the Lookup table, what about if there is a single value only? How do you do the extrapolation on this case? You would need at least two values. How to handle this scenario? Are we going to repeat the reference value? You are using `AVERAGE`, this is not an extrapolation. Extrapolation would mean you can assume a linear function for example and you extrapolate the new value that you don't have it assuming a linear equation. Are the stations unique values?

Comment: If there is only one value, a Null result (or blank) could be possible without any problem. And you're absoultely right, I used the wrong word sorry hehe There is no need to create a linear function, the average result is enough on this case. Also, the stations are not unique values, there will be several entries for 4 stations, for 5... Max number is 39

Comment: Interpolation, assuming a straight line relationship, is as simple as for a given x value getting the x & y values for just below and just above then calculation the target y value. Just need to employ vlookup() several times.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt because more clarity is needed in terms of all possible scenarios to consider, based on different input data and how to understand the  "*extrapolation*" process. This approach understands as extrapolation the average of two values (lower and greater), but the idea can be customized to any other way to calculate it. Per tags listed in the question I assume there is no Excel version constraint. This is O365 solution:

```
=LET(sm, A2:A10, st, B2:B10, jph, C2:C10, smx, F1:J1,  sty, E2:E4, NULL, "",
  GETLk, LAMBDA(x,y,mode, FILTER(jph, (st=y)
   * (sm = INDEX(sm, XMATCH(x, sm, mode))), NULL)),
  GET, LAMBDA(x,y, LET(f, FILTER(jph, (jph=GETLk(x,y, 1))
   + (jph=GETLk(x,y, -1)), NULL), IF(@f=NULL, NULL, AVERAGE(f)))),
  HREDUCE, LAMBDA(yi, DROP(REDUCE("", smx, LAMBDA(ac,x,
    HSTACK(ac, GET(x, yi)))),,1)),
  DROP(REDUCE("", sty, LAMBDA(ac,y, VSTACK(ac, HREDUCE(y)))),1))
```

The above formula spills the entire result, I don't think for this case you can use a `LOOKUP`-like function.

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

The highlighted cells where the average is calculated.

### Explanation

The main idea is to use `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK/VSTACK` pattern to generate the grid. Check my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) on how to apply it.

We use two user `LAMBDA` functions to abstract some calculations:

- `GETLk(x,y,mode)`, filters `jph` name based on **%SMALL** and **Stations** columns values, based on input values `x` (x-axis value from the grid), `y` (y-axis value form the grid) respectively. The third input argument `mode`, is for doing the approximate search in `XMATCH` (`1`-next largest, `-1` next smallest). In case the value exist in the input table, `XMATCH` returns the same value in both cases.
- `GET(x,y)` has the logic to find the value or if the value doesn't exist to calculate the average. It uses the previous `LAMBDA` function `GETLk`. We filter for `jph` values that match the input values (`x`,`y`), but we use an OR condition in the `FILTER` (`+`), to select both lower or greater values. If the value exist, returns just one value otherwise two values are returned by `FILTER` (`f`). Finally if `f` is not empty we return the average, otherwise the value we setup as `NULL`.
- `HREDUCE`: Concatenate the result by columns for a given row of the grid. Check the referred question for more information about it.