# I need to pull a complete row from one excel sheet to another escel sheet, based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 Excel worksheets. In the first I have a table that has a column named "Sales Order" and "SO Item" of each row (product) plus some other columns. In this table I concatenate "Sales Order" and "SO Item" so that I have Sales Order parent (xxxxxxx00) and also Sales Order childs (xxxxxxx01, xxxxxxx02,...,xxxxxxx09). However, in the second worksheet I also have the "concatenation" column but only contains Sales Order parents. How can I pull the whole rows containing the childs of each parent from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2?

I've tried to do it using VLOOKUP but this only returns a single child value (xxxxxxx001) and also its not returning the whole row where this code is located

Table 1 is:

| Sales Order | SO Item | Concatenation | Material Description | Feas Plan Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2503319449 | 100 | 2503319449100 | SYS-7210 SAS-Mxp | Bundle Header |
| 2503319449 | 101 | 2503319449101 | PS-7210 SAS-T/Mxp | 1/31/2023 |
| 2503319449 | 102 | 2503319449102 | SYS-7210 SAS-Mxp2VDC | Global Allocation |
| 2503319449 | 200 | 2503319449200 | OS-7210 SAS-Mxp | 1/31/2023 |

Table 2 is:

| Sales Order | SO Item | Concatenation | Material Description | Feas Plan Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2503319449 | 100 | 2503319449100 | SYS-7210 SAS-Mxp | Bundle Header |
| 2503319449 | 200 | 2503319449200 | OS-7210 SAS-Mxp | 1/31/2023 |

I want Table 2 to extract the missing "Concatenation" items from Table 1.

Comment: Please share sample data, better in Table Markdown format, you can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and also provide the expected output. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by this: ”I want Table 2 to extract the missing "Concatenation" items from Table 1”. I though Table 2 is the input table, then the result will be in other place,  not in the Table 2 itself.  Please provide the expected output for your sample data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question, how to present the output. I assume **Table2** is your lookup table. Based on the input data, you need to return the entire **Table1**, I assume your **Table1** has more data in your real case, and you want to extract just the information based on the lookup table. In the way you construct the concatenation, for the lookup it is only necessary the **SO Item** column values. Put on `G2` the following formula:

```
=LET(tbA, A3:E4, tbB, A9:E12, soA, 1*INDEX(tbA,,2), soB, 1*INDEX(tbB,,2),
  DROP(REDUCE("", soA, LAMBDA(ac,x, LET(f,
  FILTER(tbB, (soB >= x) * (soB < x+100),""), IF(@f="", ac, VSTACK(ac,f))))),1))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

The condition:

```
IF(@f="", ac, VSTACK(ac,f))
```

It is just to prevent empty result from the `FILTER` output (`f`), it is not really necessary if you want to include the parent (condition: `soB >= x` as it is in the formula), but if you want to exclude it (`soB > x`) then you need it. Check my answer to the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) on how to use `DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern. I convert to numeric values (multiplying `INDEX` by `1`) the value of **SO Item** column, in case the input data is in text format, otherwise it is not necesary.