# Index and Match multiple matches

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula, xlookup

I need help with the following query. There are 2 excel sheet and I need to find out in Sheet 1 in Column A what are the different accounts matching, the refernce is Sheet 2.

I am looking for a formula, which can give me all the account in sheet 1 in corressponds to the position nr. The anwser is in sheet 2. Can someone please help?

eg. 5001 = should give me 41150100, 41150101, 41200000

| Position | Account |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5001 |  |  |
| 5031 |  |  |
| 5051 |  |  |

| Account | Position |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41150100 | 5001 |  |
| 41150101 | 5001 |  |
| 78589545 | 5051 |  |

I am looking for a formula, which can give me all the account in sheet 1 in corressponds to the position nr. The anwser is in sheet 2. Can someone please help?

eg. 5001 = should give me 41150100, 41150101, 41200000

Comment: You could possibly adapt this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Or use TEXTJOIN and FILTER

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question, you can try the following (*formula 1*):

```
=LET(pos, A2:A4, accnt, B2:B4, REDUCE({"Account","Position"}, pos, LAMBDA(ac,p,
 VSTACK(ac,LET(f,TEXTSPLIT(@FILTER(accnt,pos=p),,","), HSTACK(f, IF(f=f, p)))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

**Notes**:

- You would need to clean up your input because in some cases the delimiter is just a comma and in other cases, a space is added.
- If the question refers to doing it backward, as @ScottCraner suggested in the comments, then assuming the output from the previous screenshot is now the input, then we have (*formula 2*):

```
  =LET(acc, D2:D8, pos, E2:E8, ux, UNIQUE(pos), out, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(p,
   TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(acc, pos=p)))), HSTACK(ux, out))
```

*formula 1*: Uses the `REDUCE/VSTACK pattern`, check my answer to the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) for more details on how to use it. In this case, we use the header to initiate the accumulator.

`TEXTSPLIT` is used to split the account information by `,` into rows. We use [implicit intersection (@)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) to convert the `FILTER` output (array of one element only) into a single string to be able to use `TEXTSPLIT`, otherwise, it returns the first element only.

We use the condition `IF(f=f, p)` to generate a constant array with the position value (`p`). `HSTACK` is used to generate the output on each iteration in the format we want (first account, then position).

A more verbose formula, but maybe easier to understand, since it doesn't use the `VSTACK/REDUCE` pattern, could be the following:

```
=LET(pos, A2:A4, accnt, B2:B4, split, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,accnt), ",",";"),
 mult, MMULT(1-ISNA(split), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(split),,1,0)),
 outP, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,REPT(pos&",",mult)),",",";",1),2),
 HSTACK(TOCOL(split,2), outP))
```

The main idea is to use `TOCOL`. The name `split`, generates the array with the account information. The name `mult`, calculates the number of columns with values. Now we know how many times we need to repeat position values. We use `REPT` to repeat the value and generate an array via `TEXTSPLIT`.

Comment: I think this backward: `5001 = should give me 41150100, 41150101, 41200000`.  I read that as the first picture is the desired outcome and the second the input.

Comment: Thanks, I read it this: "The anwser is in sheet 2" understanding that the answer would be the second table from the question. Let's see what the OP says about it, then adjust it. Now I understand your comment in the question about `TEXTJOIN`. Thanks again @ScottCraner

Comment: I may be wrong, but definitely confusing.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick response. I think my question wasn't very clear. The reference sheet is sheet 2. I want the answer in sheet 1 based on position nr. As you can see in the picture the position nr. 5001 should give me the corresponding account nr. (Its a long list over 4000 rows). Sheet 1 has only the position nr and I need the correponding Account nr, which is in sheet 2. I hope it is clear now :)

Comment: @AshSam123 did you check the formula of my notes (formula2)? I provided a solution in both direction.