# how to sum columns using column headers and bridge tables in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have two sets of data in excel, set 1 is the raw data, and set 2 is a bridge table. The desired output is also added. How should I prepare for this formula.

set 1:

[image]

set 2:

[image]

output expected:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, a solution that assumes a variable number of headers and **no specific pattern in the column names**. *Assumed no Excel version constraints as per tags listed in the question*. In cell `H1`, put the following formula which spills the entire result all at once:

```
=LET(in, A1:F5, lk, A8:B12, header, DROP(TAKE(in,1),,1), A, TAKE(lk,,1), 
 B, DROP(lk,,1), data, DROP(in,1,1), REDUCE(TAKE(in,,1), UNIQUE(B),
 LAMBDA(ac,bb, LET(f, FILTER(A, B=bb),values, CHOOSECOLS(data,XMATCH(f, header)),
  sum, MMULT(values, SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0)), HSTACK(ac, VSTACK(bb, sum))))))
```

Here it the output:
[image: excel output]

We use `LET` function with two input ranges *only*: `in`, `lk`, so the rest of the names defined depend on such range names. It makes the formula easy to maintain and to adapt to your real scenario.

Using `DROP` and `TAKE` we extract each portion of the input ranges: `header`, `data`, `A`, `B` (columns from the second table). We use `REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern to concatenate the column of the result on each iteration. Check my answer from the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) for more information.

We iterate by unique values of `B` and for each value (`bb`) we select the column `A` values (`f`). We use `XMATCH` to select the corresponding index columns from `header` (it doesn't include the date column). We use `CHOOSECOOLS` to select the corresponding columns from `data` (`values`). Now we need to sum by column, and we use `MMULT` for that. The result is in `sum` name. Finally, we use `HSTACK` to concatenate the selected columns one each iteration, including as header the unique values from `B`.

**Note**: Instead of `MMULT` function, you can use the following array function, it is a matter of personal preferences:

```
BYROW(values, LAMBDA(x, sum(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. It's out of my knowledge range, but it does work. Through my test, it seems that if there are null values or unused rows in bridge table, errors will be returned. Is it right? One more thing is that this work is to automate process from set 1 to output. If the column sequence in output has been fixed as "Date, A, C, B, how can I update this formula.

Comment: @Harry I am glad it works. To prevent empty rows in the bridge table, you can wrap the input with `TOCOL` as follows: `=LET(in, A1:F5,  lk, A8:B12, header, DROP(TAKE(in,1),,1), A, TOCOL(TAKE(lk,,1),1),B, TOCOL(DROP(lk,,1),1), data, DROP(in,1,1), REDUCE(TAKE(in,,1), UNIQUE(B), LAMBDA(ac,bb,LET(f, FILTER(A, B=bb), values, CHOOSECOLS(data,XMATCH(f, header)),sum, MMULT(values, SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0)), HSTACK(ac, VSTACK(bb, sum))))))`, try it and let me know. About your second question, please elaborate more.

Comment: @Harry about your second question, the order of the columns in the output is based on how they are presented in the bridge table. You can wrap `UNIQUE(B)` with `SORT` or `SORTBY`, to specify specific order for example or just sort the bridge table input data. Without more details it is difficult to imagine your real scenario, but I guess using `SORT(UNIQUE(B))` ensures,`A, B, C` order for example.