# SUMIF with UNIQUE criteria for multiple columns, adding all values with same name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with multiple rows and columns (hundreds), and to make it simple, it looks pretty much like this:

| Name/Date | 01/22 | 02/22 | 03/22 | 04/22 | 05/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 10 | 4 | 7 | 1 | 10 |
| Rose | 6 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| Mary | 2 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 9 |
| Juan | 9 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 10 |
| Rose | 10 | 8 | 5 | 7 | 1 |
| Juan | 6 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 9 |
| Jack | 10 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 5 |
| Mary | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Rose | 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 |

My objective is to create an array formula that sums the values for each unique name and for each date, so in the end it should look like this:

| Name/Date | 01/22 | 02/22 | 03/22 | 04/22 | 05/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 20 | 11 | 14 | 5 | 15 |
| Rose | 18 | 16 | 12 | 11 | 5 |
| Mary | 7 | 7 | 8 | 4 | 12 |
| Juan | 15 | 12 | 3 | 10 | 19 |

The restriction is that I have to get this output with functions in just one cell, and without helper columns.

Although it is not so difficult doing this using a combination of `=HSTACK()` and `=SUMIF(names,UNIQUE(names),values)`, with a different SUMIF for each date, it is not possible in this project because of the great number of columns I have to deal with and because the number of columns varies with each analysis.

I tried solving this with a combination of `=SUMIF(names,UNIQUE(names),values)` and lambda Array Formulas (Like `BYROW`, `BYCOL` and `MAP`, but I wasn't able to get anything but an error (`BYROW` can only return 1 column as output, `BYCOL` can only return 1 row, and `MAP` function returns an array of the same size as the input). What can be done to solve this?

Comment: You would have a better chance of someone helping you if you would use markdown tables instead of photos so we can copy paste.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it's my first time here

Comment: Why not just use the in-built Consolidate function (Data tab)? Ideal for this.

Comment: Main Issue in this case is automation and the fact that all this calculation is just an intermediary step, but in other cases this would be a perfect solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sum If Unique

```
=LET(tData,A1:F10,
    Data,DROP(tData,1),Headers,TAKE(tData,1),Names,TAKE(Data,,1),Values,DROP(Data,,1),
    uNames,UNIQUE(Names),uMatches,XMATCH(Names,uNames),
    cResult,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(uNames)),LAMBDA(uRow,uMatch,
        LET(rFilter,uMatches=uMatch,
            rResult,BYCOL(Values,LAMBDA(vCol,SUM(FILTER(vCol,rFilter)))),
        VSTACK(uRow,rResult)))),1),
VSTACK(Headers,HSTACK(uNames,cResult)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following array formula that spills the entire result including the header. Put in cell `H1`, the following:

```
=LET(in,A1:F10,n,DROP(TAKE(in,,1),1),nUx,UNIQUE(n),h,TAKE(in,1),d,DROP(in,1,1),
 SUMBYROW,LAMBDA(y,BYROW(nUx, LAMBDA(ux,SUM(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(d,y),n=ux))))),
 cal,REDUCE(nUx,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(h)-1),LAMBDA(ac,hh,HSTACK(ac,SUMBYROW(hh)))),
 VSTACK(h, cal))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

It uses the `REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern to concatenate the column result on each iteration of the `REDUCE` function. For more information check my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691). In this case, the accumulator (`ac`) in `REDUCE` can be initialized with the list of unique names (`nUx`).

The formula only depends on the range defined in the name `in`(input), so it is easier to maintain. The other names are defined from there (`n`-names, `nUx`-unique names, `d`-data, `h`-header), using `DROP`, `UNIQUE` and `TAKE` functions. We define a user `LAMBDA` function `SUMBYROW` for a better composition, so it is easier to understand the mentioned pattern. We invoke on each iteration this function on each column index.