# Creating multiple rows and merging columns

Tags: excel, transpose

I have the following input data:

| ID | P1 | P2 | P3 | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 30 | 400 | 50 | 60 |

And I want to change it to:

| ID | A | P | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PQ1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | PQ2 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | PQ3 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | PQ1 | 10 | 40 |
| 2 | PQ2 | 20 | 50 |
| 2 | PQ3 | 30 | 60 |
| 3 | PQ1 | 1 | 400 |
| 3 | PQ2 | 2 | 50 |
| 3 | PQ3 | 30 | 60 |

So multiple rows for each **ID**, with one column stating the number behind **P** and **Q** columns, and then two columns with the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming no excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*, you can try the following array formula, which spills the entire result including the header:

```
=LET(gr,3, in, A2:G4, pqs, B1:G1, ids, TAKE(in,,1), data, DROP(in,,1),
 t, TRANSPOSE(WRAPROWS(pqs,gr)), A, LEFT(INDEX(t,,1)) & INDEX(t,,2),
 REDUCE({"ID","A","P","Q"}, ids, LAMBDA(ac,i, LET(r, SEQUENCE(gr,,i,0),
  VSTACK(ac, HSTACK(r, A, TRANSPOSE(WRAPROWS(INDEX(data,i),gr))))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We define the length of each group under the variable `gr` (in our case is `3`). The main idea is to use `WRAPROWS` function to wrap rows by `gr`. We use it for generating the **A**, **P**, and **Q** columns. `SEQUENCE` is used to generate the column **ID**. The rest is just to use `REDUCE/VSTACK-HSTACK` pattern as it is documented in my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691).

In order to easily maintain the formula, only `in` and `pqs` names depend on the input range, the rest are names generated from them, using the `DROP` and `TAKE` functions.

Answer (score 1):

This may need some alterations depending on your Excel version, and how your inputs/outputs are formatted.

For the first column:

```
=TOCOL(HSTACK(Table1[ID],Table1[ID],Table1[ID]))
```

For the second:

```
="PQ"&MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B9#),,3),3)+1
```

, where B9 for me refers to the first cell of the new ID column.

For the third column:

```
=IFS(C9#="PQ1", XLOOKUP(B9#, Table1[ID], Table1[P1]), C9#="PQ2", XLOOKUP(B9#, Table1[ID], Table1[P2]), C9#="PQ3", XLOOKUP(B9#, Table1[ID], Table1[P3]))
```

, where C9 refers to the first cell of the "A" column.

Similarly, for the last column:

```
=IFS(C9#="PQ1", XLOOKUP(B9#, Table1[ID], Table1[Q1]), C9#="PQ2", XLOOKUP(B9#, Table1[ID], Table1[Q2]), C9#="PQ3", XLOOKUP(B9#, Table1[ID], Table1[Q3]))
```

As I said, this might need some alterations, but let me know if so.