# Transform Excel table into lists below each table parameter (and skip blanks)

Tags: excel, datatables, transform

I know there are similar questions, and I've tried to use all of the codes mentioned in them - but something isn't working for me. Please help.

My **input** is an excel table set up like this:

| VISITCODE | dm1 | dm2 | dm3 | dm4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| thing1 |  | B | A | A |
| thing2 | A | B | B |  |
| thing3 | A | B | A |  |
| thing4 | B |  | B | A |

[image]

I'd like the **output** to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Power Query is a good way to unpivot your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Excel formulas. The following spills the entire result including the headers all at once:

```
=LET(in,A1:E5, h,TAKE(in,1), data,DROP(in,1), nh, {"VISIT CODE","Req","Type"},
 t, TAKE(data,,1), REDUCE(nh,DROP(h,,1),LAMBDA(ac,x, LET(
  col, INDEX(data,,XMATCH(x,h)), f, FILTER(HSTACK(t, col), col<>""), n, ROWS(f), 
  fill, IF(SEQUENCE(n)<=n,""), VSTACK(ac, VSTACK(HSTACK(x,"",""), 
  HSTACK(fill, f)))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

It uses `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern, check my answer to the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691). The following:

```
IF(SEQUENCE(n)<=n,"")
```

is a trick to generate an array of empty values on each iteration (but there are multiple ways of doing it, this is just one of them). We filter by non-empty rows (`f`) on each iteration. The rest is just to accommodate the information into the desired output format on each iteration.

All the required variables depend only on a single range (`in`) so it is easier to maintain. We play with `DROP` and `TAKE` to extract the information we need from `in`.

If you don't want to generate the title, here is the updated formula:

```
=LET(in,A1:E5, h,TAKE(in,1), data,DROP(in,1),
 t, TAKE(data,,1), DROP(REDUCE("",DROP(h,,1),LAMBDA(ac,x, LET(
 col, INDEX(data,,XMATCH(x,h)), f, FILTER(HSTACK(t, col), col<>""), n, ROWS(f), 
 fill, IF(SEQUENCE(n)<=n,""), VSTACK(ac, VSTACK(HSTACK(x,"",""), 
 HSTACK(fill, f)))))),1))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the "titles" or with a data set that has different dimensions? I want to apply this to a variety of different projects that will all be formatted the same - but would have different column titles and have many more columns/rows.