# How to transpose data in an other tab in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for transposing a table into an other tab in Excel.

My first table :

```
First_Name | Last_Name | Company   | Number  | Done (1 = yes / 0 = no)
-----------------------------------------------------
Allison    | Dark      ! McDonald  | 2,00    |  1
John       | Doe       | Amazon    | 10,00   |  1
Julian     | Smith     | Coca Cola | 3,00    |  0
Kathy      | Johnson   | Coca Cola | 20,00   |  1
Barbara    | Brown     | Tesco     | 10,00   |  0
Alexander  | Lee       | Amazon    | 4,00    |  0
Harry      | Moore     | Amazon    | 8,00    |  0
```

How can I retrieve these data in an other tab like this:

```
Company   | Number of names | Done   |  Sum of Numbers 
------------------------------------------------------
Amazon    |     3           | 1 on 3 |   22,00
Coca Cola |     2           | 1 on 2 |   23,00
McDonald  |     1           | 1 on 1 |   2,00
Tesco     |     1           | 0 on 1 |   10,00
```

I was looking for a formula but it also can be in vba.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a perfect scenario for the use of a pivot table.

Comment: What did you try? As a start, for column A you can use UNIQUE, for column B COUNTIF, same for C. And SUMIF for D. Or pivot table as @MadMarc says

Comment: Thx for these tips. I cannot use UNIQUE because of my old version. And yes, I could use Pivot Table but I was wondering how I can do it without pivot table but a formula with LOOKUP for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With older versions of Excel to get unique list you may copy all *Company* list and use excel function *"Remove duplicates"* or place formula in `A13` and drag it down till it gets empty:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$8, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$12:A12, $C$2:$C$8), 0)),"")
```

To get company name count paste in `B13` and drag down:

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$8,A13)
```

For "Done" in `C13`:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$8,A13,$E$2:$E$8,1)&" of "&COUNTIF($C$2:$C$8,A13)
```

For sum of numbers in `D13`:

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$8,A13,$D$2:$D$8)
```

Result:

[image]

Adapt ranges to your data and new table destination.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*. This is another application of the `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern, you can check my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691). The formula spills the entire result including the header and returning the result sorted by company name. Put on `G1` the following:

```
=LET(in, A1:E8, h, TAKE(in,1), data, DROP(in,1), cmp, INDEX(data,,3),ux, 
 SORT(UNIQUE(cmp)), done, INDEX(data,,5), amnt, INDEX(data,,4), 
 header, {"Company","Number of Names","Done","Sum of Numbers"}, CALC, LAMBDA(x, 
 LET(a, cmp=x, b, SUM(N(a)), c, SUM((a)*(done=1)), 
 HSTACK(x, b, c&" on "&b,SUM(a*amnt)))), REDUCE(header, ux, LAMBDA(ac,x, 
 VSTACK(ac, CALC(x)))))
```

**Note:** Updated the formula looking at @VBasic2008 I realized the companies can be sorted first, which allows for reducing the formula.

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The user `LAMBDA` function `CALC` does the calculation to generate an entire row on each iteration of `REDUCE`. We can not use the header to initialize the accumulator (`ac`), because we need to sort the result first.

Answer (score 1):

### Transform Data (Excel Formula)

**Improved (Edit)**

- After applying David Leal's suggestions in the comments, it looks like this:

```
=LET(d,C2:E8,del," on ",dCols,3,
    co,TAKE(d,,1),u,SORT(UNIQUE(co)),
HSTACK(u,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(u),dCols,LAMBDA(r,c,
    LET(cc,MOD(c,dCols)+c-1,f,co=INDEX(u,r,1),
        fr,ROWS(FILTER(co,f)),s,SUM(INDEX(d,,cc)*f),
IF(cc=1,fr,IF(cc=2,s,s&del&fr)))))))
```

[image]

**Initial**

```
=LET(d,C2:E8,del," on ",
    co,TAKE(d,,1),u,SORT(UNIQUE(co)),
HSTACK(u,MAKEARRAY(4,3,LAMBDA(r,c,
    LET(cc,MOD(c,3)+c-1,f,co=INDEX(u,r,1),
IF(cc=1,ROWS(FILTER(co,f)),
     LET(s,SUM(FILTER(INDEX(d,,cc),f)),
IF(cc=2,s,s&del&ROWS(FILTER(co,f))))))))))
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach and avoids using `REDUCE/VSTACK`, which may be not efficient for very large data. I need to get familiar with the `MAKEARRAY` alternative.

Comment: @DavidLeal I try to avoid it when possible. I'm not quite sure about `ROWS(FILTER(co,f))`. Would it be better placed in the 2nd `LET` (it's only used for columns 1 and 3)?

Comment: I thinks it is possible, the following is a shorter approach under the same idea: `=LET(d,C2:E8,del," on ",co,TAKE(d,,1),u,SORT(UNIQUE(co)), HSTACK(u,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(u),3,LAMBDA(r,c, LET(cc,MOD(c,3)+c-1,f,co=INDEX(u,r,1), cnts, ROWS(FILTER(co, f)), s, SUM(INDEX(d,,cc)*f), IF(cc=1,cnts, IF(cc=2,s,s&del&cnts)))))))` I get the same result. I use `ROWS(u)` instead of `4`

Comment: @DavidLeal I knew an intervention was needed. Thanks for the suggestions. The 4 was really a ridiculous mistake but getting rid of FILTER, that one I have to memorize. I implemented all of it.