# Count the number of times a specific value appears in a column when there are more than one value in some of the rows

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, measure

Please is there a measure or DAX in power bi that can be used to count the number of times a specific value appears in a column when there are more than one value in some of the rows?

For example;

[image: Table X]

I don' want to unpivot the table because it will mess with the other data in the table.

Result

[image: Table X]

Comment: You could do a `COUNTIF` with the criteria surrounded by wildcards if you want to keep it simple eg. `=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&C1&"*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already generated a table (named *Values*) comprising a single-column (named *Value*) of distinct values ("AA", "AB", "AC", for example), create this **measure**:

```
=
VAR ThisValue =
    MIN ( 'Values'[Value] )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Table1, SEARCH ( ThisValue, Table1[Value],, 0 ) > 0 ) )
```

and add it to your visual alongside the *Value* field from the *Values* table.

Answer (score 2):

**step1**. create column & measure for AA,AB,AC:

COLUMN:

```
AA = if(search("AA",[Value],,0)>0,1,0)
```

MEASURE:

```
AA measure = sum('Value'[AA])
```

same as AB,AC.
[image]

**step2.** create new table:

```
Result = datatable(
"Category",STRING,
{{"AA"},{"AB"},{"AC"}})
```

**step3.** add column in new table:

```
Value = switch(true(),
[Category]="AA",[AA measure],
[Category]="AB",[AB measure],
[Category]="AC",[AC measure])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it using Excel formulas only, you can try the following. Put in cell `C1`, the following formula:

```
=LET(A, A2:A8,values,DROP(REDUCE("",A,LAMBDA(ac,x,
 VSTACK(ac,TEXTSPLIT(x,,"; ",1)))),1), ux, UNIQUE(values), cnts, 
 BYROW(ux, LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(values=x)))),
 VSTACK({"Category","Result"},HSTACK(ux, cnts)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

For more information check my answer to the following question related to the `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691).

If you don't have a large dataset that after joining the entire column won't reach the max cell size (`32,767` number of characters), then you can try the following:

```
=LET(A, A2:A8, values,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,A),"; ",",",1),2),
 ux, UNIQUE(values), cnts,BYROW(ux, LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(values=x)))),
 VSTACK({"Category","Result"}, HSTACK(ux, cnts)))
```

The second solution is about `100x` faster than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Do following in Power Query

1. First split column by delimiter ;
2. Unpivot the columns
3. Trim text in column
4. Group By value and count rows

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]