# Split values from a single column to different individual columns in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to split the values available in parent column to three individual columns as shown in the picture.

[image: picture shows example for putting each value in separate columns]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming entries in `A1:A9`:

```
=LET(
    λ,3,
    ζ,A1:A9,
    IF(
        MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ζ),λ,LAMBDA(α,β,INDEX(MUNIT(λ),1+MOD(α,λ),1+MOD(β,λ)))),
        IF(SEQUENCE(,λ),ζ),
        ""
    )
)
```

Amend the initial definition for λ (3 here) to determine the number of columns to return in the output.

Comment: I didn't know MUNIT, but it is perfect for this!

Comment: @P.b Yes, perhaps with the new dynamic array functionality in O365 we might see more uses for that function.

Answer (score 3):

A succinct alternative using `MAKEARRAY`:

```
=LET(n,3,A,A1:A9,m,ROWS(A),MAKEARRAY(m,n,
 LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c=MOD(r-1,n)+1,INDEX(A,r),""))))
```

or *even a shorter*, not using `MAKEARRAY` which is **probably more efficient**, since it doesn't use a `LAMBDA` function:

```
=LET(n,3,A,A1:A9,m,ROWS(A),IF(N(MOD(SEQUENCE(m,,0),n)+1=SEQUENCE(,n))=1,A,""))
```

where `MOD(SEQUENCE(m,,0),n)+1` generates the sequence: `{1;2;3;1;2;3...;1;2;3}` until `m` for `n=3` for example. It is actually the array version of `MOD(r-1,n)+1` from the first formula.

and

```
N(MOD(SEQUENCE(m,,0),n)+1=SEQUENCE(,n))
```

stacks vertically `n`-times the unit matrix (i.e. `MUNIT(n)`), similar to what does the `REDUCE/VSTACK` approach, see below, but without using a `LAMBDA` function:

```
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
```

Here is the output (for the first approach):
[image: output]

Another alternative using `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern(1), maybe less efficient for large dataset (when `n` is a small number, i.e. it requires a high number of iterations), but probably easier to understand:

```
=LET(n,3,A,A1:A9,u,MUNIT(n), x,REDUCE(u,SEQUENCE(n-1),
 LAMBDA(ac,_,VSTACK(ac,u))),IF(x=1,A,""))
```

(1) Check my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691).

Comment: So I was testing on a larger dataset today around `200K` found the 2nd works like a lightning fast ! Also Sir, you can golf it by removing the `N()` --> `=LET(n,3,A,A1:A9,m,ROWS(A),IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(m,,0),n)+1=SEQUENCE(,n),A,""))`

Answer (score 0):

with list starting at A3, modify accordingly

```
Sub CutAndMove()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 4 To lastRow Step 3
        Range("A" & i).Cut Destination:=Range("B" & i)
    Next i
    
    For i = 5 To lastRow Step 3
        Range("A" & i).Cut Destination:=Range("C" & i)
    Next i
End Sub
```