# Excel - how can I combine rows by ID and put the row with different date as the last column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks below:

| id | date | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03 /02/2023 | Apple |
| 1 | 03 /01/2023 | Orange |
| 1 | 03 /01/2023 | Banana |
| 2 | 03 /01/2023 | Kiwi |
| 2 | 03 /01/2023 | Apple |
| 2 | 02 /14/2023 | Orange |

How can I make the same id into one row, and make sure that the item with the different date is on the last column? Like below:

| id | item1 | item2 | item3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Orange | Banana | Apple |
| 2 | Kiwi | Apple | Orange |

Thanks!

Comment: Can you guarantee there will be only 3 IDs and only one date will differ? And it is undefined if it would be greater or lower than the other two?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @Horaciux Yes there are only 3 IDs and only one date will differ. It's not guaranteed if it would be greater or lower than the other two

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. *Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*.

```
=LET(A,A2:A7, B,B2:B7, C,C2:C7, ux,UNIQUE(A), cnts,COUNTIFS(A,A,B,B),
 h,HSTACK("id", "item"&SEQUENCE(,ROWS(A)/ROWS(ux))),
 REDUCE(h,ux,LAMBDA(ac,x,VSTACK(ac,
 HSTACK(x,TOROW(SORTBY(FILTER(C,A=x),FILTER(cnts,A=x),-1)))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

`h` name represents the header and `cnts`, the counts of dates per `id`.
We use `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern(1) to iterate over unique **id** column values. On each iteration, we use `SORTBY` to sort `C` by `cnts` in reverse order filtering by **id** column values (`A`) equal to `x`, then we convert the result to a row-array via `TOROW` and append it to `x` via `HSTACK`.

(1) Check my answer to the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691).