# Find the most common text in a column if another column matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Person | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Apple |
| Adam | Apple |
| Adam | Banana |
| Sally | Banana |
| Sally | Banana |
| Sally | Strawberry |

In another Excel sheet I am trying to pull the above data into the bottom:

| Person | 1st most | 2nd most |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Apple | Banana |
| Sally | Banana | Strawberry |

I know

```
=INDEX(Entry!D:D,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(Entry!D:D,Entry!D:D)),COUNTIF(Entry!D:D,Entry!D:D),0))
```

gives me the top value in the column which in the example would be Banana rather then per person.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following, *assuming no Excel version constraint as per the tags listed in your question* (*formula1*):

```
=LET(in,A2:B7, A,TAKE(in,,1), B,TAKE(in,,-1), ux,UNIQUE(A),
 cnts,UNIQUE(HSTACK(A,B,COUNTIFS(A,A,B,B))), h,{"Person","1st Most","2nd most"},
 REDUCE(h,ux,LAMBDA(ac,x,LET(f,FILTER(cnts,TAKE(cnts,,1)=x),
   VSTACK(ac,HSTACK(x,TOROW(TAKE(SORTBY(INDEX(f,,2), TAKE(f,,-1),-1),2))))))))
```

You can also use `LARGE` instead of `SORTBY` for this case as follows (*formula 2*):

```
=LET(in,A2:B7, A,TAKE(in,,1), B,TAKE(in,,-1), ux,UNIQUE(A),
 cnts,UNIQUE(HSTACK(A,B,COUNTIFS(A,A,B,B))), h,{"Person","1st Most","2nd most"},
 REDUCE(h,ux,LAMBDA(ac,x,LET(f,FILTER(cnts, TAKE(cnts,,1)=x),fc,TAKE(f,,-1),
  out,XLOOKUP(LARGE(fc,{1,2}),fc,INDEX(f,,2)),VSTACK(ac,HSTACK(x,TOROW(out)))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

In *formula 1*, the name `cnts`, has the first two columns from the input, plus the counts per **Person** per **Fruit** columns, selecting unique rows. Then we use `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern(1), to iterate over all unique **Person** column values. On each iteration we filter `cnts` by person (`x`) and name it `f`, then we use `SORTBY` by the number of counts (last column of `f`) in reverse order (`-1`) to sort the fruits (second column of `f`) and take only the first two values. Convert the result to a row via `TOROW` and append the result to `x` via `HSTACK`.

(1) Check my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[image]

The formula I forgot to put in the image is the one in cell F2:

```
UNIQUE(B2:B7)
```

Then you can use index () with match() and Max() or large() to pull out the top 2 etc etc