# Excel formula to create one row for each subject, and replace missing value in a column with the next available value for a particular subject

Tags: excel, replace, formula

I have a table as below,

| ID | Name | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | BOB |  |  |  | Y |
| A1 | BOB |  | Y |  |  |
| A1 | BOB |  |  |  |  |
| A1 | BOB | Y |  |  |  |
| B1 | SAM |  |  |  |  |
| B1 | SAM |  |  |  |  |
| B1 | SAM |  |  | Y | Y |
| B1 | SAM |  |  |  |  |
| B1 | SAM |  | Y |  |  |
| C1 | TOM |  |  | Y |  |
| C1 | TOM |  |  |  |  |
| C1 | TOM |  |  |  |  |
| C1 | TOM |  |  | Y |  |
| C1 | TOM | Y |  |  |  |
| C1 | TOM | Y |  | Y |  |
| --- | ---- | ------ | ---- | ------ | ---- |

I want to create a table as shown below. That is, only one final row for each ID, and if any row of that ID has "Y" in a particular year, the final row will have an "Y"

| ID | Name | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | BOB | Y | Y |  | Y |
| B1 | SAM |  | Y | Y | Y |
| C1 | TOM | Y |  | Y |  |
| --- | ---- | ------ | ---- | ------ | ---- |

I googled but failed to find an answer

Comment: What is your excel version? Is it Microsoft 365?

Answer (score 3):

This is just one of a number of possible ways. If the tables are arranged as in the screenshot, put this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16, $A19, C$2:C$16, "Y") > 0, "Y", "")
```

in cell `C19`. Copy to the rest of the output table `C19:F21` and you're done.

The `COUNTIFS` statement matches both the IDs in column A and the entries in each year column. The `IF` statement should be obvious. Be careful with the dollar signs in the references, they're critical here.

[image: Solution spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1):

Here an array version that spills the entire result, *assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tag listed in the question*:

```
=LET(in,A1:F16, h,TAKE(in,1), data,DROP(in,1),ux,UNIQUE(TAKE(data,,2)),
 REDUCE(h, SEQUENCE(ROWS(ux)), LAMBDA(ac,a, VSTACK(ac, HSTACK(INDEX(ux,a,),
  BYCOL(FILTER(DROP(data,,2), TAKE(data,,1)=INDEX(ux,a,1)),
   LAMBDA(f, IF(SUM(N(f="Y"))>0, "Y",""))))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

This is just another application of `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern (1). It depends on a single data range (`in`, i.e. easier to maintain), and then combining `TAKE` and `DROP` functions extract the necessary information. It iterates over all row index position of `ux` (Unique rows from the first two columns of `data`). On each iteration, concatenate the given row `a` via `HSTACK` with the output of `BYCOL`. This function uses as input the data with year information (without the header), filtered by iteration id (`INDEX(ux,a,1)`), then on each columns counts the numbers of `Y`s, in case the counts is greater than `0`, put on that column `Y` otherwise an empty string.

(1): Check my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691).