# Get right hand non-date value in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have numerous sheets of thickness readings. They take the form of something similar to:

| ITEM | POS | BASETHK | BASEDATE | THICKNESS | THK DATE | THICKNESS | THK DATE | THICKNESS | THK DATE | THICKNESS | THK DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | **4.8** | **22/05/11** | 4.9 | 13/06/23 | 5.3 | 25/09/19 | 5.1 | 11/06/15 | **4.8** | **22/05/11** |
| 002 | B | **8.2** | **11/06/15** | 8.1 | 13/06/23 | 8.0 | 25/09/19 | **8.2** | **11/06/15** | N | 22/05/11 |
| 003 | C | **7.4** | **22/05/11** | 7.1 | 13/06/23 | N | 25/09/19 | 7.6 | 11/06/15 | **7.4** | **22/05/11** |

The number of columns after the Item and Position can vary, depending on how many readings we have but, if there isn't a reading one year, the survey date is still entered and an 'N' (for No Reading) is entered.

What I need to get (in the BASETHK and BASEDATE cells) is the rightmost thickness reading for one, and the respective date for the other. I've made the results in the BASE columns bold, and also the cells they're getting their results from.

for the thickness and date columns, there is always one of each for each year's survey, so the BASETHK looks at the rightmost thickness and the BASEDATE looks at the rightmost date for that thickness.

Is this possible? I've Google lots, and tried LOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH and so on, but without real success.

Excel version: 365

Comment: Put your desired output to the post. Also mention your Excel version?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated to say the version. Regarding the output, I need the results (so formulas) in the BASE columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for BASETHK:

```
=INDEX(2:2,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E2:$L2)/($E$1:$L$1="THICKNESS")/($E2:$L2<>"N"),1))
```

and this for BASEDATE:

```
=INDEX(2:2,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($E2:$L2)/($E$1:$L$1="THICKNESS")/($E2:$L2<>"N")+1,1))
```

You shall specify a proper range if $E2:$L2 or $E$1:$L$1 do not cover the reasonably expected width of data and headers.

Solution developed and tested on Excel 2016. 365 might have a better one so you may wait for others to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=LET(x,IFERROR(XMATCH(FALSE,E2:L2<>"N",0,-1)-1,MAX(COLUMN(E2:L2))-COLUMN($D$1)),CHOOSECOLS(E2:L2,x-1,x))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice approach. This is a tweak of your formula to spill it and to make sure that if a `N` is submitted somewhere, it will still search for the minimum date without an `N` submitted next to it:
`=LET(a,E2:L4,b,D2:K4,c,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(a),0),r,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),d,MAP(r,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,MIN(TOROW(INDEX(a,x,)/(ISODD(INDEX(c,1,)))/(INDEX(b,x,)<>"N"),3)),XMATCH(y,INDEX(a,x,))))),INDEX(a,r,d-{1,0}))`

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm afraid I can't follow it to see the difference!

Comment: @ShaunAllan Check the values for the 3rd row the sample you updated. My comment version returns `7.4 22/05/11` Haruns version will return `7.1 13/06/23` (values left from the last found `N`). Also with mine it spills all results at once.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an array solution, that spills the entire result all at once. Put in cell `C1`, the following *formula 1*:

```
=LET(in, E2:L4, REDUCE({"BASETHK","BASEDATE"}, SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)), LAMBDA(ac,s,
 LET(x, WRAPROWS(INDEX(in,s,),2), 
  idx,XMATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(TAKE(x,,1)*TAKE(x,,-1)),,-1),
 VSTACK(ac,INDEX(x,idx,))))))
```

Here is another alternative that doesn't use the `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern(1). This pattern is usually less efficient for a large dataset (*formula 2*):

```
=LET(in, E2:L4, n,COLUMNS(in), rseq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)), cseq,SEQUENCE(n/2,,,2),
   a, CHOOSECOLS(in,cseq), b, CHOOSECOLS(in,cseq+1),
   idx,2*BYROW(ISNUMBER(a*b), LAMBDA(x, XMATCH(TRUE,x,,-1))),
   VSTACK({"BASETHK","BASEDATE"},
     HSTACK(INDEX(in,rseq,idx-1),INDEX(in,rseq,idx))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The input range (`in`) can be extended to the maximum number of columns among all rows, for example it works if you extend it to  `E2:Z4`, if the maximum column from the input range is the column `Z`.

*formula 1*: uses the `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern(1). On each iteration of `REDUCE` it selects the row `s` from the input range (`in`) via `INDEX(in,s,)`, then invoke on `WRAPROWS` to wrap the row for every two columns and name `x`. The first column of `x` has the **BASETHK** column values and the second column the **BASEDATE** values for a given row. Now we need to find using reverse search (`-1` in `XMATCH`), where both columns of `x` are numeric (`idx`). Having the index position, we can invoke `INDEX(x,idx,)` to extract all columns for a given index position. It uses `VSTACK` to concatenate vertically the result of each iteration, where the first row is the header.

*formula 2*: `rseq` represents row number of the input `in` and `cseq`, represents the column index positions for odds columns. The names `a`,`b` the **BASETHK** and **BASEDATE** column values. The condition we are looking for is when `a*b` is a number. We iterate over all values of `BYROW` (`x`) to find when it is `TRUE` doing a reverse search in `XMATCH` (`-1`). The result of `BYROW` has the index position of such values. It multiplies by `2`, since we spit the range by `2`. Now we have the index positions `idx` with respect the initial range `in`. Finally we use `INDEX` function to find the corresponding values for each row.

(1) [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691)