# reshaping table with excel

Tags: excel, reshape

I have the next table in excel

```
|Id |name |last name |boss |boss mail |
______________________________________________
|id1|name1|last name1|boss1|boss mail1|
|id2|name2|last name2|boss2|boss mail2|
|id3|name3|last name3|boss1|boss mail1|
```

and I need to group by boss and put the other variables horizontaly like this:

```
|boss |boss mail |id_1|name_1|last name_1|id_2|name_2|last name_2|
__________________________________________________________________
|boss1|boss mail1|id1 |name1 |last name1 |id3 |name3 |last name3 |
|boss2|boss mail2|id2 |name2 |last name2 | NA | NA   | NA        |
```

This is for 321 lines and just using excel, because I don't have access to R or Python :(
Any idea of how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) It’s very similar to what you’re asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
      _u, UNIQUE(D2:E4),
      HSTACK(_u,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",TAKE(_u,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,
      VSTACK(x,TOROW(FILTER(A2:C4,D2:D4=y))))),""),1)))
```

---