# Move values from column to rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I change my data from this form

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1 |
| A | A2 |
| A | A3 |
| B | B1 |
| B | B2 |
| C | C1 |
| C | C2 |
| C | C3 |
| C | C4 |

into this

| ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | A2 | A3 |  |
| B | B1 | B2 |  |  |
| C | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single cell dynamic array formula using `LAMBDA()` helper functions -- `MAKEARRAY()`.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _ID, TAKE(A2:B10,,1),
     _Value, TAKE(A2:B10,,-1),
     _UniqueID, UNIQUE(_ID),
     _Rows, ROWS(_UniqueID),
     _Columns, MAX(COUNTIFS(_ID,_ID)),
     _Transform, MAKEARRAY(_Rows, _Columns, LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(FILTER(_Value, _ID=INDEX(_UniqueID,r)),c))),
     _Headers, HSTACK("ID", SEQUENCE(,_Columns)),
     _Combined, HSTACK(_UniqueID, IFERROR(_Transform,"")),
     VSTACK(_Headers, _Combined))
```

---

Using `POWER QUERY` will be more apt here as it can handle quite a lot amount of datasets, so to achieve this using the said procedure, follow these simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"All", each _, type table [ID=text, VALUE=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Expanded Index" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Index", {"ID", "VALUE", "Index"}, {"ID", "VALUE", "Index.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Index", {{"Index.1", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Index", {{"Index.1", type text}}, "en-US")[Index.1]), "Index.1", "VALUE")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using the Power Query -option. Your other suggestion using Lambda() functions didn't work, probably because the Excel version (or US vs Europe?) differences. Many "," should have been ";" instead and probably some other modifications to the code. But the Power Query -method worked straight away. Well, had to change "Value" into "VALUE" in the header, but apart from that :)

Answer (score 2):

### Transform Data (Pivot)

[image]

```
=LET(data,A1:B10,ucol,1,vcol,2,
    sd,DROP(data,1),
    uc,INDEX(sd,,ucol),
    vc,INDEX(sd,,vcol),
    u,UNIQUE(uc),
    v,IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",u,LAMBDA(rr,r,
        VSTACK(rr,TOROW(FILTER(vc,uc=r))))),1),""),
    dh,HSTACK(INDEX(data,1,ucol),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(v))),
    dd,HSTACK(u,v),
VSTACK(dh,dd))
```

Comment: `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern is very handy in a situation like this considering that is it not too efficient for a large dataset. It can be simplified by initializing the accumulator with the first row. I use also `COUNTIFS` to get the max count. Check my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the new [Pivotby](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/new-aggregation-functions-groupby-and-pivotby/ba-p/3965765) function:

```
=LET(id,A2:A10,
value,B2:B10,
ser,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(id)),LAMBDA(a,I,IFS(I=1,1,INDEX(id,I)=INDEX(id,I-1),a+1,TRUE,1))),
PIVOTBY(id,ser,value,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0,,0))
```

[image]

As you can see, I haven't yet found a way of displaying the row header (ID) but not the column header:

```
=LET(id,A1:A10,
value,B1:B10,
ser,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(id)),LAMBDA(a,I,IFS(I=1,"hdr",INDEX(id,I)=INDEX(id,I-1),a+1,TRUE,1))),
PIVOTBY(id,ser,value,ARRAYTOTEXT,3,0,,0))
```

[image]

But you could show headers then drop the first row of the output:

```
=LET(id,A1:A10,
value,B1:B10,
ser,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(id)),LAMBDA(a,I,IFS(I=1,"hdr",INDEX(id,I)=INDEX(id,I-1),a+1,TRUE,1))),
DROP(PIVOTBY(id,ser,value,ARRAYTOTEXT,3,0,,0),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of @VBasic2008 solution. It uses [REDUCE/VSTACK pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) which is not efficient for a large dataset, but easier to understand. For a large dataset, it might behave better @MayukhBhattacharya approach.

```
=LET(ID,A2:A10, val,B2:B10, IDux,UNIQUE(ID),maxCols,MAX(COUNTIFS(ID, IDux)),
 IFERROR(REDUCE(HSTACK("ID", SEQUENCE(,maxCols)), IDux, LAMBDA(ac,a,
  VSTACK(ac, HSTACK(a, TOROW(FILTER(val,ID=a)))))),""))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

there is a formula will work in all excel versions

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,AGGREGATE(15,3,(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-1)/($A$2:$A$10=$E2),COLUMNS($E$2:E2))),"")
```

[image]