# In Excel, how can I count the number of instances of a string in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, countif

I have a column with different staff members who have attended an event on different dates. Sometimes it is only one person attending, sometimes it is multiple. I want to be able to calculate how many times each individual staff member has attended. I have tried `COUNTIF()`, but that won't pick up the occasions when more than one person has attended.

| Staff attending |
| --- |
| Ben |
| John |
| Dave |
| Mark |
| Ben, John |
| Mark, John |
| Ben & Dave |
| Mark & John |

In the above table I want to be able to calculate how many times each individual staff member has attended.

I apologise in advance, I'm sure this question has been asked and answered on occasions, but I probably lack awareness of the syntax and how to verbalise my query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted, then one could use `GROUPBY()` presently available in `MS365` `Beta Channel` then the following should work.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _StaffAttending, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A9," &",","),", ",SEQUENCE(,10)),", "),2),
     GROUPBY(_StaffAttending,_StaffAttending,COUNTA,0,0))
```

---

To make things more clearer, the above formula can be expanded to few more steps:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _SameDelimiters, SUBSTITUTE(A2:A9," &",","),
     _CountDelimiters, LEN(_SameDelimiters)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_SameDelimiters,", ",)),
     _Instance_Num, SEQUENCE(,MAX(_CountDelimiters)),
     _SplitByRow, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&_SameDelimiters,", ",_Instance_Num),", "),2),
     _Output, GROUPBY(_SplitByRow,_SplitByRow,COUNTA,0,0),
     _Output)
```

---

Or, Using `MMULT()` with same steps applied like above except it uses `MMULT()` to get the number counts by doing matrix multiplication of two arrays.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _StaffAttending, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A9," &",","),", ",SEQUENCE(,10)),", "),2),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_StaffAttending, MMULT(N(_StaffAttending=TOROW(_StaffAttending)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_StaffAttending),,,0)))))
```

---

Or, Using `POWER QUERY` will be more apt here as it can handle quite a lot amount of datasets, so to achieve this using the said procedure, follow these simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

---

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source," &",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Staff attending"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value", {{"Staff attending", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Staff attending"),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Staff attending", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"Staff attending"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

However, one could also accomplish this using `COUNTIFS()` or `COUNTIF()` using `wildcard operator *` if the staffs names are listed manually, then

[image]

---

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,"*"&C2:C5&"*")
```

---

To list unique names of the staffs those attended, can use:

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A9," &",","),", ",SEQUENCE(,10)),", "),3))
```

---

All the above solutions posted are without using any `LAMBDA()` iterations as well don't use `TEXTJOIN()` function and the reason to avoid the latter specifically as *there are character limitations for the said function if it exceeds the limit will render `#VALUE!` error.* And we are not aware of how large the dataset is as well as whether the dataset has full names or first names only. However, posting as an alternative:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Split, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,A2:A9),,{"|",", "," & "}),
     GROUPBY(_Split, _Split, COUNTA,,0,))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     _Split, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,A2:A9),,{"|",", "," & "}),
     PIVOTBY(_Split,, _Split, COUNTA,,0,))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Split, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,A2:A9),,{"|",", "," & "}),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Split,MMULT(N(_Split=TOROW(_Split)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Split),,,0)))))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

There are so many methods. Here's one more:
*`Staff_attending` is the range of names as shown in your example, eg: `A2:A9`*

```
=LET(
    nms, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", , Staff_attending), , {"&", ","})),
    u, UNIQUE(nms),
    cnts, BYROW(u, LAMBDA(arr, SUM(--(arr = nms)))),
    VSTACK({"Staff", "Attended"}, HSTACK(u, cnts))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(
    a, B3:B10,
    b, UNIQUE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a), 10, LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(a, r), {" ",",","&"}, , 1), c))), 2)),
    c, MAP(b, LAMBDA(x, ROWS(TOCOL(SEARCH(x, a), 2)))),
    d, HSTACK(b, c),
    d
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This approach avoids using [JOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) due to the cell limit `32767` for a large dataset. Using [REDUCE/VSTACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) pattern (may incur performance issues for a large dataset) results in a short formula and easy to understand.

```
=LET(in, A2:A9,names, DROP(REDUCE("",in,LAMBDA(ac,a, VSTACK(ac, 
 TEXTSPLIT(a,,{", "," & "})))),1), uxNames, UNIQUE(names), 
 HSTACK(uxNames, BYROW(uxNames, LAMBDA(n, SUM(N(names=n))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

An alternative to `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern would be:

```
=LET(in, SUBSTITUTE(A2:A9, "&", ","), del, ", ",
 cntDel, MAX(LEN(in) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(in,",","")))+1,
 names, TOCOL(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(del & in, del, 
  SEQUENCE(,cntDel)),del)),2),
 uxNames, UNIQUE(names),
 HSTACK(uxNames,BYROW(uxNames, LAMBDA(n, SUM(N(names=n))))))
```

It was spotted by @MayukhBhattacharya in the formula which uses `TEXTAFTER` to get the unique names. The name `cntDel`, counts the maximum number of delimiters. It is used to set the `TEXTAFTER` input argument: `instance_num`. One is added because when it invokes `TEXTAFTER`, is added a delimiter at the beginning of `in`. `TEXTSPLIT` is intended to be used for texts. When we use it for an array it only returns the first split, that is the trick we use here combined with the `instance_num` to get all the split values. `TOCOL` with input argument `2` is used to remove `#N/A` values when there is no such instance number. Once we have `names` and `uxNames`, it is just a simple calculation using `BYROW` to count repeated values for a given unique name `n`.

**Note**: Usually `MMULT` is more efficient than using `BYROW` (but a longer formula), so you can use instead: `MMULT(N(uxNames=TOROW(names)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(names),,,0))`