# How to return second most frequent word within column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how to return the MOST frequently occurring string in Excel, but how do I return the SECOND most frequently occurring text from a column that has multiple words?

[image]

In this image here, one can see strings with one, two, and three words. One row has RMBS, and another has ABS, RMBS, and CMBS.

I tried index matching, using mode, countIF, but did not manage to achieve wanted results. The two results I kept getting were "CMBS," and "ABS, CMBS, RMBS."

| Service |
| --- |
| RMBS |
| RMBS |
| ABS, CMBS |
| ABS, CMBS |
| CMBS |
| CMBS |
| ABS |
| CMBS |
| CMBS |
| CMBS |
| ABS |
| ABS, CMBS, RMBS |
| CMBS |
| ABS, RMBS |
| ABS, RMBS |
| ABS |
| ABS, CMBS, RMBS |
| ABS, CMBS |
| CMBS |
| RMBS |
| ABS, CMBS, RMBS |
| ABS, CMBS, RMBS |
| ABS, CMBS |
| ABS, CMBS, RMBS |
| CMBS |
| CMBS |

Comment: Try this: `=LET(RNG,A1:A12,spt,REDUCE("",RNG,LAMBDA(z,y,VSTACK(z,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(y,","))))),INDEX(SORT(GROUPBY(spt,spt,COUNTA,0,0),2,-1),2,1))`

Comment: This question already has an answer, only needs and `INDEX()` function to take 2nd one. Look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77773532/8162520)**

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing this:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _NOfDelim, MAX(LEN(A2:A27)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A27,",",))+1),
     _ActualData, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&A2:A27,", ",SEQUENCE(,_NOfDelim)),", "),
     _SingleCol, TOCOL(_ActualData,2),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_SingleCol),
     INDEX(SORT(HSTACK(_Uniq, BYROW(_Uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM(--(x=_SingleCol))))),2,-1),2,1))
```

---

- `_NOfDelim` --> This gives the max count of the delimiters in the array.
- `_ActualData` --> Splitting the data into `#` of columns based on the `_NOfDelim` using `TEXTAFTER()` & `TEXTSPLIT()`
- `_SingleCOl` --> Converting the array into a one single array.
- `_Uniq` --> Using `UNIQUE()` function taking the unique values.
- Lastly, with the help of `BYROW()` function passing a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations to get no of counts for each `_Uniq`, once we get the counts, merging along with `_Uniq` using `HSTACK()`. Next to get the `2nd Frequent` text, using `SORT()` function to sort it by counts in descending order and then using `INDEX()` to take the second value in the array.

---

Using `GROUPBY()` & `MAKEARRAY()`

```
=LET(
     _NOfDelim, MAX(LEN(A2:A27)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A27,",",))+1),
     _Array, TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:A27),_NOfDelim,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A2:A27,r),", ",,1),c))),2),
     INDEX(GROUPBY(_Array,_Array,COUNTA,,0,-2),2,1))
```

---

And without using any `LAMBDA()` helper functions:

```
=LET(
     _NOfDelim, MAX(LEN(A2:A27)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A27,",",))+1),
     _Array, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&A2:A27,", ",SEQUENCE(,_NOfDelim)),", "),2),
     INDEX(GROUPBY(_Array,_Array,COUNTA,,0,-2),2,1))
```

---

We could actually use much shorter step to resolve this issue however, using the shorter routes sometimes leads to pitfalls which we often ignore. Using `TEXTJOIN()` or any functions which helps in combining strings into one has a character limitation as per the `MSFT` Documentations, which says, if the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters per cell limit then it will return a `#VALUE!` error, which means when we are joining multiple cells into one large string it may or may not depending on ones data has chances of returning error(Hence the reason why we avoid, at the very beginning). However, here is one way:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Services, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",,A2:A27),,", "),
     INDEX(GROUPBY(_Services, _Services, COUNTA,,0,-2),2,1))
```

---

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem for me, although if I do find it quite overwhelming to understand. May I ask for an explanation as to why the formula is written the way it is? I want to understand what makes it work!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This was really useful. I should really learn more so that I can get comfortable with these types of formulas, although being honest, I don't really know where to start, haha!

Answer (score 3):

My two cents:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=LET(s,A2:A27,d,", ",r,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(d&s,d,SEQUENCE(,MAX((LEN(s)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(s,d,)))/LEN(d))+1)),d),3),@DROP(GROUPBY(r,r,ROWS,0,0,-2),1))
```

Whatever answer you go for, I highly encourage you to avoid anything that join's your data together first (`TEXTJOIN()` or `ARRAYTOTEXT()`).

Comment: similar to Mayukh's approach, with the innovation of using `GROUPBY` for doing the match instead of `BYROW`. Great tip. I look forward to using these new functions, but it is not available in the free Excel Web yet.

Comment: @DavidLeal not similar to my approach. Those ideas are exclusively developed by JvdV sir, I just follow. Also it is JvdV sir who has posted that trick and idea in this forum first. And later most of the users used that in their answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't profess to be able to do these things (because I'm still learning) as efficiently as others but this lays it out in a way that is quite easy to follow if you want to break it down bit by bit ...

```
=LET(
  _concatenatedData, TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, Table1[Service]),
  _splitByCommaData, TRANSPOSE(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(_concatenatedData, ","))),
  _distinctValues, UNIQUE(_splitByCommaData, FALSE),
  _withCount, HSTACK(_distinctValues, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_distinctValues), 1, LAMBDA(r,c,  ROWS(FILTER(_splitByCommaData, _splitByCommaData=CHOOSEROWS(_distinctValues, r)))))),
  _sortedByCountDesc, SORT(_withCount, 2, -1),
  _secondEntry, TAKE(_sortedByCountDesc, 1, 1),
_secondEntry)
```

... you'd just need to change out `Table1[Service]` to include your table name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it.

Assume your original tags are in `A1:A26`.

To create a flat list of all tags, you can do this:

`=TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(A1:A26,0),", "))`

Step by step:

`ARRAYTOTEXT(range,0)` creates a very long text string from all cells (`0` tells it to put string in one cell)

`TEXTSPLIT(long_string,", ")` splits the string in a very long row of cells with one tag in each. Note ", " instead of just ","! This extra space should be removed at some point, and best when the data is imported to Excel.

`TOCOL(cell_row)` transposes row to column.

Now you can use the result with `UNIQUE()` to create a list of three tags, `COUNTIF()` to count them and `LARGE()` to get nth largest value. If you wish, I can amend the answer to wrap them all in one huge formula that will return the tag but it will be rather bulky.

Comment: This is a great idea, but you cannot use `COUNTIF` with an array, it must be a range. Here a complete solution: `=LET(keys,TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(A2:A27),,", "), ux,UNIQUE(keys), cnts,BYROW(ux, LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(keys=x)))), XLOOKUP(LARGE(cnts,2),cnts,ux))`

Comment: @DavidLeal on no now you can ) `=MAP(unique_tags,LAMBDA(unique_tag,COUNTIF(all_tags,unique_tag)))`

Comment: @DavidLeal of course once you put it all together in a single formula it will get bulky. wrapping it in let make it shorter but still, too many levels IMO. I personally would use advanced formula editor at this point

Comment: I don't think your approach using `COUNTIF` works for the reason I provided. Try the following: `=LET(z,{1;1;2}, u,UNIQUE(z),ta,MAP(u,LAMBDA(x, COUNTIF(z,x))),tb,MAP(u,LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(z=x)))),tb)` if you try to return `ta` you get `#CALC!`. In our case the list of keys is an array not a range, because it is obtained as a result of a calculation via `TEXTSPLIT`.

Comment: See my comment on Dang D. Khanh's answer, this applies also to `ARRAYTOTEXT` since it puts everything in a single cell, so it can reach the cell limit for a large dataset.

Comment: @DavidLeal this is a known problem for TEXTJOIN() but to the best of my knowledge no one encountered it yet for ARRAYTOTEXT() that was designed to avoid other problems that TEXTJOIN() had - such as failure on parsing stocks and other smart tags etc. If anyone breaks it on cell length, will be fun to see. Excel is not the best environment for bulk text processing but for extremely large datasets if I really have to do it there, I prefer mapping or playing dumb and adding helper columns.

Comment: It is not hard to break the limit, you need just a large dataset, with a large string on each cell. Anyway, something to consider when dealing with such kinds of scenarios, other than that is a very concise approach. Let's say you have a dynamic range that keeps growing, then you may reach the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a name `FS.NTH`

```
=LAMBDA(x,k,LET(y,MATCH(x,x,0),IF(k=1,INDEX(x,MODE(y)),IF(k>1,FS.NTH(FILTER(x,y<>MODE(y)),k-1),NA()))))
```

Then please try this :)

`DATA=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",,$A$1:$A$28), ,", ")`

```
=LET(DATA,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",,$A$1:$A$28), ,", "),FS.NTH(DATA,2))
```

[image]

OR

`DATA=REDUCE(,A1:A28,LAMBDA(A,B,VSTACK(A,TEXTSPLIT(B,,", "))))`

[image]

Comment: this is a good approach, but keep in mind the Remarks note from [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) specification: *If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), TEXTJOIN returns the #VALUE! error.* A reason to avoid this function in case of a large dataset or large texts to join.

Comment: @DavidLeal, you can somehow have DATA, not necessarily `TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",,$A$1:$A$30)`, see my update!