# excel counting values within a column with multiple rows where values are separated by commas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I am trying to count value.

- I have 1 column with multiple rows (more rows will be added with time)
- each row has the text value of city names separated by commas: CHICAGO, DALLAS, NEW YORK, LONDON, ROME
- cities will remain the same over time

I am trying to calculate the "count" per city = ex. how many times DALLAS is mentioned within that column (the commas make it more difficult for me to count)

can you please try to help me, this is the excel file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/23flbts6eh9e6h3effsuv/stackoverflow-counting-issue-laire.xlsx?rlkey=22wmoxxcuf2bs3o4k5hjtfzir&dl=0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL6Qs.png)

thanks in advance for helping
best
dnv

Comment: This already has a solution [Check_Here_Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77773532/8162520)

Comment: thank you. i tried the LET and countif formulas but it does not work... not sure what i am doing wrong. i tried for NY and Paris see  F52 and F53 thank you! https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/23flbts6eh9e6h3effsuv/stackoverflow-counting-issue-laire.xlsx?rlkey=22wmoxxcuf2bs3o4k5hjtfzir&dl=0

Comment: I tried all the formulas posted in the link all worked on my end. I see you get `#NAME` error thats because may be it doesnt support however there are formulas posted using `COUNTIFS()` with wild card which should work: `=COUNTIFS(A2:A49,"*"&TRIM(E52)&"*")`

Comment: I have tested all the formulas then only i have marked it duplicate. Please try. If you dont have any of those, then also there is an alternative posted for older versions using `COUNTIFS()` with wildcard as well as `Power Query` the link is full of proper solutions. Everyone who has posted has posted neat solutions. I have posted at last of my answers with `COUNTIFS()` as well. check!

Comment: great, thank YOU so much, this =COUNTIFS(A2:A49,"*"&TRIM(E52)&"*") works great. thanks again for your help