# How to merge multiple rows into one row in excel?

Tags: excel, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple rows into one row in excel. I have added a screenshot of what my problem is.

[image: sample of problem]

I want to get all numbers into one row (row 2 in this case). I've already tried the Power Query technique, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

To give you context, my dataset has nearly 2000 rows.

Does anyone know of any easy way to merge all rows into 1 row?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply group the rows by the first column, this is the M code that does it in a single step ...

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Column1"}, {{"1", each List.Sum([1]), type nullable number}, {"2", each List.Sum([2]), type nullable number}, {"3", each List.Sum([3]), type nullable number}, {"4", each List.Sum([4]), type nullable number}, {"5", each List.Sum([5]), type nullable number}, {"6", each List.Sum([6]), type nullable number}, {"7", each List.Sum([7]), type nullable number}, {"8", each List.Sum([8]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Power Query, this way:

- insert a Table (ListObject) using the data you want to group
- pivot > unpivot them as in the M code below:

```
    let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyListObjectName"]}[Content],
        #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
        #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
    in
        #"Pivoted Column"
```

Column1 is intended here to be the sheet's Column "A"

Comment: M code didn't got formatted as piece of code. Maybe because I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel functions as follows, assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tag listed in the question. I assume in the real case, there is more than one Village. This solution puts village information on the first row for each village. Put in the cell `A10` the following formula.

```
=LET(in, A1:I8, h,TAKE(DROP(in,,1),1), data,DROP(in,1), v,TAKE(data,,1),
 d,DROP(data,,1), seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)), uxV,UNIQUE(v),
 idx, XMATCH(uxV,v), emptyRow, IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d))>0,""),
 calc,REDUCE(h, seq, LAMBDA(ac,s, VSTACK(ac, IF(ISNA(XMATCH(s, idx)), emptyRow,
   BYCOL(FILTER(d, v=INDEX(v,s)), LAMBDA(c, @FILTER(c, c<>"",""))))))),
 HSTACK(VSTACK("",v), calc))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The name `in` identifies the entire input dataset, and then it combines `DROP/TAKE` functions to extract a specific portion of the input, such as `v` for villages, `d` for data. It assumes you want to collect all the information on the first row where we have a new village. The name `idx` identifies the index positions of each new village (assuming the same villages are together). To generate an empty row we use the following trick: `IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d))>0,"")` and name it `emptyrow`.

Then it generates the output (`calc`) using [REDUCE/VSTACK pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691). The accumulator is initialized with the header (`h`). It iterates through each rows index (`s`) and checks if the `s` index matches the start of the new village using `ISNA(XMATCH(s, idx))`. If the index is not found, then it generates an empty row. Otherwise, it filters `d` for a given village (`v=INDEX(v,s)`), then the output of the `FILTER` will be the input of `BYCOL` to find non-empty values via `@FILTER(c, c<>"","")` for each column for a given village. It uses the [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) to get just the first result of `FILTER`. Assuming per column there is just one value for each village.

Finally, we use `HSTACK` to accommodate the final output.