# Excel - how to create a column indicating conflict?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My first Excel spreadsheet looks like:

| Student | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

There is a separate spreadsheet for the day and times of the courses. I would like to create a new column titled "conflict" in the first spreadsheet. This conflict would indicate whether there's a conflict (yes/no) in the student's schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this in a new sheet:

| Student | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:T1)) | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:U1)) | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:V1)) | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:W1)) | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:X1)) | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:Y1)) | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:Z1)) | =INDEX($N$4:$N$11,COLUMNS($T$1:AA1)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | =SUM(COUNTIF($T$4:$AA$11,SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN($B$1:$I$1)/B2:I2-COLUMN($B$1:$I$1),0,"")&$B$1:$I$1&"|"&TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN($B$1:$I$1)/B2:I2-COLUMN($B$1:$I$1),0,"")&$B$1:$I$1))) | =IF(J2>0,"Conflict","-") |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:T2)) | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:U2)) | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:V2)) | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:W2)) | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:X2)) | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:Y2)) | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:Z2)) | =INDEX($R$4:$R$11,COLUMNS($T$2:AA2)) |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | =SUM(COUNTIF($T$4:$AA$11,SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN($B$1:$I$1)/B3:I3-COLUMN($B$1:$I$1),0,"")&$B$1:$I$1&"|"&TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN($B$1:$I$1)/B3:I3-COLUMN($B$1:$I$1),0,"")&$B$1:$I$1))) | =IF(J3>0,"Conflict","-") |  |  | Course | day | time start | time end |  |  | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:T3)) | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:U3)) | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:V3)) | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:W3)) | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:X3)) | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:Y3)) | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:Z3)) | =INDEX($S$4:$S$11,COLUMNS($T$3:AA3)) |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | =SUM(COUNTIF($T$4:$AA$11,SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN($B$1:$I$1)/B4:I4-COLUMN($B$1:$I$1),0,"")&$B$1:$I$1&"|"&TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(COLUMN($B$1:$I$1)/B4:I4-COLUMN($B$1:$I$1),0,"")&$B$1:$I$1))) | =IF(J4>0,"Conflict","-") |  |  | a | Mon | 07:00 | 10:00 | =VLOOKUP(O4,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P4 | =VLOOKUP(O4,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q4 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T4)=ROWS($T$4:T4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<T$3,$S4>=T$3),AND($R4>=T$2,$S4<=T$3),AND($S4>T$2,$R4<=T$2))),$N4&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U4)=ROWS($T$4:U4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<U$3,$S4>=U$3),AND($R4>=U$2,$S4<=U$3),AND($S4>U$2,$R4<=U$2))),$N4&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V4)=ROWS($T$4:V4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<V$3,$S4>=V$3),AND($R4>=V$2,$S4<=V$3),AND($S4>V$2,$R4<=V$2))),$N4&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W4)=ROWS($T$4:W4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<W$3,$S4>=W$3),AND($R4>=W$2,$S4<=W$3),AND($S4>W$2,$R4<=W$2))),$N4&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X4)=ROWS($T$4:X4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<X$3,$S4>=X$3),AND($R4>=X$2,$S4<=X$3),AND($S4>X$2,$R4<=X$2))),$N4&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y4)=ROWS($T$4:Y4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<Y$3,$S4>=Y$3),AND($R4>=Y$2,$S4<=Y$3),AND($S4>Y$2,$R4<=Y$2))),$N4&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z4)=ROWS($T$4:Z4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<Z$3,$S4>=Z$3),AND($R4>=Z$2,$S4<=Z$3),AND($S4>Z$2,$R4<=Z$2))),$N4&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA4)=ROWS($T$4:AA4),FALSE,OR(AND($R4<AA$3,$S4>=AA$3),AND($R4>=AA$2,$S4<=AA$3),AND($S4>AA$2,$R4<=AA$2))),$N4&"|"&AA$1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | b | Mon | 08:00 | 11:00 | =VLOOKUP(O5,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P5 | =VLOOKUP(O5,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q5 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T5)=ROWS($T$4:T5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<T$3,$S5>=T$3),AND($R5>=T$2,$S5<=T$3),AND($S5>T$2,$R5<=T$2))),$N5&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U5)=ROWS($T$4:U5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<U$3,$S5>=U$3),AND($R5>=U$2,$S5<=U$3),AND($S5>U$2,$R5<=U$2))),$N5&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V5)=ROWS($T$4:V5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<V$3,$S5>=V$3),AND($R5>=V$2,$S5<=V$3),AND($S5>V$2,$R5<=V$2))),$N5&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W5)=ROWS($T$4:W5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<W$3,$S5>=W$3),AND($R5>=W$2,$S5<=W$3),AND($S5>W$2,$R5<=W$2))),$N5&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X5)=ROWS($T$4:X5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<X$3,$S5>=X$3),AND($R5>=X$2,$S5<=X$3),AND($S5>X$2,$R5<=X$2))),$N5&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y5)=ROWS($T$4:Y5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<Y$3,$S5>=Y$3),AND($R5>=Y$2,$S5<=Y$3),AND($S5>Y$2,$R5<=Y$2))),$N5&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z5)=ROWS($T$4:Z5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<Z$3,$S5>=Z$3),AND($R5>=Z$2,$S5<=Z$3),AND($S5>Z$2,$R5<=Z$2))),$N5&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA5)=ROWS($T$4:AA5),FALSE,OR(AND($R5<AA$3,$S5>=AA$3),AND($R5>=AA$2,$S5<=AA$3),AND($S5>AA$2,$R5<=AA$2))),$N5&"|"&AA$1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | c | Tue | 09:00 | 12:00 | =VLOOKUP(O6,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P6 | =VLOOKUP(O6,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q6 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T6)=ROWS($T$4:T6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<T$3,$S6>=T$3),AND($R6>=T$2,$S6<=T$3),AND($S6>T$2,$R6<=T$2))),$N6&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U6)=ROWS($T$4:U6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<U$3,$S6>=U$3),AND($R6>=U$2,$S6<=U$3),AND($S6>U$2,$R6<=U$2))),$N6&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V6)=ROWS($T$4:V6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<V$3,$S6>=V$3),AND($R6>=V$2,$S6<=V$3),AND($S6>V$2,$R6<=V$2))),$N6&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W6)=ROWS($T$4:W6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<W$3,$S6>=W$3),AND($R6>=W$2,$S6<=W$3),AND($S6>W$2,$R6<=W$2))),$N6&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X6)=ROWS($T$4:X6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<X$3,$S6>=X$3),AND($R6>=X$2,$S6<=X$3),AND($S6>X$2,$R6<=X$2))),$N6&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y6)=ROWS($T$4:Y6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<Y$3,$S6>=Y$3),AND($R6>=Y$2,$S6<=Y$3),AND($S6>Y$2,$R6<=Y$2))),$N6&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z6)=ROWS($T$4:Z6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<Z$3,$S6>=Z$3),AND($R6>=Z$2,$S6<=Z$3),AND($S6>Z$2,$R6<=Z$2))),$N6&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA6)=ROWS($T$4:AA6),FALSE,OR(AND($R6<AA$3,$S6>=AA$3),AND($R6>=AA$2,$S6<=AA$3),AND($S6>AA$2,$R6<=AA$2))),$N6&"|"&AA$1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | d | Wed | 08:00 | 11:00 | =VLOOKUP(O7,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P7 | =VLOOKUP(O7,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q7 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T7)=ROWS($T$4:T7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<T$3,$S7>=T$3),AND($R7>=T$2,$S7<=T$3),AND($S7>T$2,$R7<=T$2))),$N7&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U7)=ROWS($T$4:U7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<U$3,$S7>=U$3),AND($R7>=U$2,$S7<=U$3),AND($S7>U$2,$R7<=U$2))),$N7&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V7)=ROWS($T$4:V7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<V$3,$S7>=V$3),AND($R7>=V$2,$S7<=V$3),AND($S7>V$2,$R7<=V$2))),$N7&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W7)=ROWS($T$4:W7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<W$3,$S7>=W$3),AND($R7>=W$2,$S7<=W$3),AND($S7>W$2,$R7<=W$2))),$N7&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X7)=ROWS($T$4:X7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<X$3,$S7>=X$3),AND($R7>=X$2,$S7<=X$3),AND($S7>X$2,$R7<=X$2))),$N7&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y7)=ROWS($T$4:Y7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<Y$3,$S7>=Y$3),AND($R7>=Y$2,$S7<=Y$3),AND($S7>Y$2,$R7<=Y$2))),$N7&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z7)=ROWS($T$4:Z7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<Z$3,$S7>=Z$3),AND($R7>=Z$2,$S7<=Z$3),AND($S7>Z$2,$R7<=Z$2))),$N7&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA7)=ROWS($T$4:AA7),FALSE,OR(AND($R7<AA$3,$S7>=AA$3),AND($R7>=AA$2,$S7<=AA$3),AND($S7>AA$2,$R7<=AA$2))),$N7&"|"&AA$1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | e | Wed | 11:00 | 14:00 | =VLOOKUP(O8,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P8 | =VLOOKUP(O8,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q8 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T8)=ROWS($T$4:T8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<T$3,$S8>=T$3),AND($R8>=T$2,$S8<=T$3),AND($S8>T$2,$R8<=T$2))),$N8&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U8)=ROWS($T$4:U8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<U$3,$S8>=U$3),AND($R8>=U$2,$S8<=U$3),AND($S8>U$2,$R8<=U$2))),$N8&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V8)=ROWS($T$4:V8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<V$3,$S8>=V$3),AND($R8>=V$2,$S8<=V$3),AND($S8>V$2,$R8<=V$2))),$N8&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W8)=ROWS($T$4:W8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<W$3,$S8>=W$3),AND($R8>=W$2,$S8<=W$3),AND($S8>W$2,$R8<=W$2))),$N8&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X8)=ROWS($T$4:X8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<X$3,$S8>=X$3),AND($R8>=X$2,$S8<=X$3),AND($S8>X$2,$R8<=X$2))),$N8&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y8)=ROWS($T$4:Y8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<Y$3,$S8>=Y$3),AND($R8>=Y$2,$S8<=Y$3),AND($S8>Y$2,$R8<=Y$2))),$N8&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z8)=ROWS($T$4:Z8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<Z$3,$S8>=Z$3),AND($R8>=Z$2,$S8<=Z$3),AND($S8>Z$2,$R8<=Z$2))),$N8&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA8)=ROWS($T$4:AA8),FALSE,OR(AND($R8<AA$3,$S8>=AA$3),AND($R8>=AA$2,$S8<=AA$3),AND($S8>AA$2,$R8<=AA$2))),$N8&"|"&AA$1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | f | Wed | 13:00 | 16:00 | =VLOOKUP(O9,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P9 | =VLOOKUP(O9,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q9 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T9)=ROWS($T$4:T9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<T$3,$S9>=T$3),AND($R9>=T$2,$S9<=T$3),AND($S9>T$2,$R9<=T$2))),$N9&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U9)=ROWS($T$4:U9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<U$3,$S9>=U$3),AND($R9>=U$2,$S9<=U$3),AND($S9>U$2,$R9<=U$2))),$N9&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V9)=ROWS($T$4:V9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<V$3,$S9>=V$3),AND($R9>=V$2,$S9<=V$3),AND($S9>V$2,$R9<=V$2))),$N9&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W9)=ROWS($T$4:W9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<W$3,$S9>=W$3),AND($R9>=W$2,$S9<=W$3),AND($S9>W$2,$R9<=W$2))),$N9&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X9)=ROWS($T$4:X9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<X$3,$S9>=X$3),AND($R9>=X$2,$S9<=X$3),AND($S9>X$2,$R9<=X$2))),$N9&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y9)=ROWS($T$4:Y9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<Y$3,$S9>=Y$3),AND($R9>=Y$2,$S9<=Y$3),AND($S9>Y$2,$R9<=Y$2))),$N9&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z9)=ROWS($T$4:Z9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<Z$3,$S9>=Z$3),AND($R9>=Z$2,$S9<=Z$3),AND($S9>Z$2,$R9<=Z$2))),$N9&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA9)=ROWS($T$4:AA9),FALSE,OR(AND($R9<AA$3,$S9>=AA$3),AND($R9>=AA$2,$S9<=AA$3),AND($S9>AA$2,$R9<=AA$2))),$N9&"|"&AA$1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | g | Thu | 08:00 | 11:00 | =VLOOKUP(O10,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P10 | =VLOOKUP(O10,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q10 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T10)=ROWS($T$4:T10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<T$3,$S10>=T$3),AND($R10>=T$2,$S10<=T$3),AND($S10>T$2,$R10<=T$2))),$N10&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U10)=ROWS($T$4:U10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<U$3,$S10>=U$3),AND($R10>=U$2,$S10<=U$3),AND($S10>U$2,$R10<=U$2))),$N10&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V10)=ROWS($T$4:V10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<V$3,$S10>=V$3),AND($R10>=V$2,$S10<=V$3),AND($S10>V$2,$R10<=V$2))),$N10&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W10)=ROWS($T$4:W10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<W$3,$S10>=W$3),AND($R10>=W$2,$S10<=W$3),AND($S10>W$2,$R10<=W$2))),$N10&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X10)=ROWS($T$4:X10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<X$3,$S10>=X$3),AND($R10>=X$2,$S10<=X$3),AND($S10>X$2,$R10<=X$2))),$N10&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y10)=ROWS($T$4:Y10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<Y$3,$S10>=Y$3),AND($R10>=Y$2,$S10<=Y$3),AND($S10>Y$2,$R10<=Y$2))),$N10&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z10)=ROWS($T$4:Z10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<Z$3,$S10>=Z$3),AND($R10>=Z$2,$S10<=Z$3),AND($S10>Z$2,$R10<=Z$2))),$N10&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA10)=ROWS($T$4:AA10),FALSE,OR(AND($R10<AA$3,$S10>=AA$3),AND($R10>=AA$2,$S10<=AA$3),AND($S10>AA$2,$R10<=AA$2))),$N10&"|"&AA$1) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | h | Fri | 08:00 | 11:00 | =VLOOKUP(O11,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+P11 | =VLOOKUP(O11,{"Mon","0";"Tue","1";"Wed","2";"Thu","3";"Fri","4";"Sat","5";"Sun","6"},2,FALSE)+Q11 | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:T11)=ROWS($T$4:T11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<T$3,$S11>=T$3),AND($R11>=T$2,$S11<=T$3),AND($S11>T$2,$R11<=T$2))),$N11&"|"&T$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:U11)=ROWS($T$4:U11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<U$3,$S11>=U$3),AND($R11>=U$2,$S11<=U$3),AND($S11>U$2,$R11<=U$2))),$N11&"|"&U$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:V11)=ROWS($T$4:V11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<V$3,$S11>=V$3),AND($R11>=V$2,$S11<=V$3),AND($S11>V$2,$R11<=V$2))),$N11&"|"&V$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:W11)=ROWS($T$4:W11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<W$3,$S11>=W$3),AND($R11>=W$2,$S11<=W$3),AND($S11>W$2,$R11<=W$2))),$N11&"|"&W$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:X11)=ROWS($T$4:X11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<X$3,$S11>=X$3),AND($R11>=X$2,$S11<=X$3),AND($S11>X$2,$R11<=X$2))),$N11&"|"&X$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Y11)=ROWS($T$4:Y11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<Y$3,$S11>=Y$3),AND($R11>=Y$2,$S11<=Y$3),AND($S11>Y$2,$R11<=Y$2))),$N11&"|"&Y$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:Z11)=ROWS($T$4:Z11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<Z$3,$S11>=Z$3),AND($R11>=Z$2,$S11<=Z$3),AND($S11>Z$2,$R11<=Z$2))),$N11&"|"&Z$1) | =IF(IF(COLUMNS($T$4:AA11)=ROWS($T$4:AA11),FALSE,OR(AND($R11<AA$3,$S11>=AA$3),AND($R11>=AA$2,$S11<=AA$3),AND($S11>AA$2,$R11<=AA$2))),$N11&"|"&AA$1) |

Answer (score 0):

The following is an array version, i.e. it doesn't require expanding the formula. It assumes the first spreadsheet has all the courses from the second spreadsheet in the same order. If that is not the case the formula can be easily adjusted. It also assumes no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question. Put in cell `J2` the following formula:

```
=LET(tba,B2:I4,tbb,A8:D15,dd,INDEX(tbb,,2),ss,INDEX(tbb,,3),ee,TAKE(tbb,,-1),
 map, UNIQUE(MAP(dd,ss,ee, LAMBDA(d,s,e, LET(f,(dd = d) * (s < ee) * (e > ss),
  IF(SUM(f)>1, TEXTJOIN(",",,f),""))))),
 olap, FILTER(map, map<>""),
 check, BYROW(tba, LAMBDA(ra, SUM(BYROW(olap,
  LAMBDA(rb, N(SUM(ra * TEXTSPLIT(@rb,","))>1)))))),
 IF(check > 0,"yes", "no"))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

What it does is first work with the reference course table (`tbb`) to identify the overlapping intervals (`olap`). It takes each of the columns of interest, i.e. `dd`-days, `ss`-start dates, `ee`-end dates, and checks for the overlapping condition via `MAP` function:

```
(dd = d) * (s < ee) * (e > ss)
```

it returns an array (`f`) with `0`-`1` values. The condition for overlapping is that that sum is greater than one (because each row always overlaps with itself). If there is no overlap, then it returns the empty string. If row `x` overlaps with row `y`, therefore row `y` overlaps with row `x`. That is why it wraps the `MAP` output with `UNIQUE` to remove duplicates. Now `map` has the unique overlaps, plus the non-overlaps (empty rows). Finally, it filters by excluding empty rows from `map` and the name `olap` (overlaps) will have the following information:

```
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
```

Each row is a text delimited by coma (`,`), indicating the overlaps, as we can see courses `a,b` overlaps and `e,f` too. This is what we need to verify using the name `check`. It iterates over each row (`ra`) of `tba` via `BYROW` and for each row `ra` we check if there are any overlaps with `olap` rows. It uses a second `BYROW` for that. The statement:

```
N(SUM(ra * TEXTSPLIT(@rb,","))>1)
```

does the magic. First, it converts to a row array the corresponding row (`rb`) via `TEXTSPLIT`. Then multiply the values, if there is an overlap (more than one conflicting course is present) for a given case (we have two overlap intervals), then the sum would be greater than `1`, otherwise, there is no overlap. Using `N` function, it converts the condition to `1`-`0` values.

Finally, it sums the result of the inner `BYROW`. If any `check` row has a non-zero value, it means the student schedule has a conflict with at least one of the overlapping intervals. The final `IF` statement just accommodates the result to the expected output.

**Notes**:

- We need to use `TEXTJOIN` to avoid a [Nested Array error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-calc-error-nested-array-ffa5997d-a440-4e41-aae9-8b39c4a8dfb9). `TEXTJOIN` can be avoided, by generating a matrix using [REDUCE/VSTACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) pattern, but it will end up with a larger formula. Based on the use case provided in the question, it doesn't seem the number of courses will be as high or large to reach the limit of [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) resulting in a string bigger than `32767` characters (cell limit).
- The [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34#:%7E:text=What%20is%20implicit%20intersection%3F,only%20contain%20a%20single%20value.) is required in the inner `BYROW` since we are working with `TEXTSPLIT`. Check this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/another-issue-with-byrow/m-p/3777828).
- The formula only has a dependency on the input via `tba`,`tbb` names. Assigning the corresponding input ranges the rest of the formula should work for any variable range.

Answer (score 0):

You already have some answers, but this may be helpful in another way since it doesn't say *if* it's a conflict, but *what* is the conflict:

```
=LET(a,CONCAT(REPT($B$1:$I$1,B2:I2)),TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT({"a&b","e&f"},ISNUMBER(FIND({"ab","ef"},a)))))
```

It concatenates the header values where that row's value contains a `1` and checks if `"ab"` and/or `"ef"` is found (the only two variants that are a conflict situation) and returns these values.

[image]