# Excel - Count and sum of consecutive profits by account number, count not resetting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying for a couple of days and I've been beaten, I am looking for a formula in D2 that looks for the maximum number of consecutive times each account number is profitable (the records are in chronological order top to bottom). I'm also looking for the sum of those consecutive trades also in E2.

I'm using the below formula in D2 down for the count, it is correctly counting up each time there is a positive record, and it also sets the count to 0 when there is a negative record, however the next positive record per account number it keeps the count increasing  from before the last reset to 0.

In short my formula isn't resetting the count, it's just adding a zero on negative records.

Any guidance to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.  I've also created a table below that shows the data I'm using and also what the result would be if anyone is curious.

Thank you.

| Account No | Helper | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2101822 | TRUE | -11.4 |
| 2101822 | TRUE | 1.58 |
| 656546 | TRUE | 100 |
| 656546 | TRUE | 100 |
| 2101822 | TRUE | 100 |
| 2101822 | TRUE | 1001 |
| 2101822 | TRUE | -100 |
| 2101822 | TRUE | 1000 |
| 656546 | TRUE | -1.6 |
| 656546 | TRUE | 100 |
| 656546 | TRUE | 150 |

result

| Account Number | Most Consecutive Profits # | Total Consecutive Profits $ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2101822 | 3 | 1102.58 |
| 656546 | 2 | 150 |

Comment: Is your data grouped by account numbers and sorted by date before this analysis starts? Or is it a coincidence?

Comment: Why the expected outcome of profit for `656546` is 150? Shouldn't it be 250? Anyways, not sure if this can be achieved with a single formula. Probably you'll need a macro

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a less-verbose way to do this, but meanwhile try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=REDUCE({"Account Number","Most Consecutive Profits #","Total Consecutive Profits $"},UNIQUE(A2:A12),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TAKE(SORT(REDUCE({0,0,0},FILTER(C2:C12,A2:A12=y),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(y,IF(b>0,INDEX(TAKE(a,-1),2)+1,0),IF(b>0,INDEX(TAKE(a,-1),3)+b,0))))),{2,3},-1),1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted then using `MS365` formulas one could use the following to get the desired output:*

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, A2:A12,
     δ, UNIQUE(α),
     φ, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(δ),2,LAMBDA(r,c,
        LET(x,FILTER(B2:B12,α=INDEX(δ,r)),
            y,SCAN(0,x,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b>0,a+1,0))),
            z,SCAN(0,x,LAMBDA(d,e,IF(e>0,d+e,0))),
            f,FILTER(HSTACK(y,z),y=MAX(y)),INDEX(FILTER(f,TAKE(f,,-1)=MAX(TAKE(f,,-1))),,c)))),
     HSTACK(δ, φ))
```

---

- The above solution clearly works without any fail, I have posted another answer to show that all the formulas posted in this post, using `LAMBDA()` gives the same output.
- To explain a few for those who are not very much aware of using `LAMBDA()` helper functions, here is it:
- Using `LET()` to define variables and making the formula easy to read.
- Using `UNIQUE()` function returning the unique a/c nos.
- Using `MAKEARRAY()` a `LAMBDA()` helper function which is not recursive in behavior, used to run some custom `LAMBDA()` calculations, which returns the arrays of outputs, with the specified `#` of rows and cols respectively.
- within the above used `FILTER()` function to return the profits based on unique a/c nos.
- Now, running two `SCAN()` functions to returns a rolling sum<sup>(2)</sup> as well as a rolling counts<sup>(1)</sup> if the returned profit is greater than `0`. So that said, the latter one checks and returns a sequence like `1`,`2` ; `1`,`2`,`3` etc respectively with reference to the a/cs
- So based on those above two `SCAN()` returns doing a filtering to get the max counts of a/cs and then doing another filtering to return the max profits.
- Lastly but not least, wrapping within a `HSTACK()` to merge both the variables `δ` and `φ` to return the requisite output.

---

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya please check your solution, it doesn't return the expected results, with the current version, I am getting: `{2101822,6,6;656546,5,5}`. I am using Excel Web, the free version, just in case the reason is some version differences.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya sorry for the downvote you got, I did not intend with my comment to harm you by someone else downvoting it. I wanted to share that I am not getting the expected result given the possibility of some Excel version differences. We are all here to share and learn. Situations like that are an opportunity to learn. I am sharing the testing file [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7IihSREXoR92mFVeSp?e=kYg6vN) in case you would like to test it. For some reason, I copy and paste your formula and it gets the wrong result. If you know the reason great, if not let's move on. Thks

Comment: Man you have completely taken wrong column and then posting comments that the formula is not working please see the link you have posted I have updated also you should write that you have made a mistake by writing that comment and the formula is certainly working

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya clarified the situation, you removed the `B` column from the question since it is not relevant, I assumed you kept it as it is in the question. That is the reason for the diffrent result I got. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the question, the goal is to find the maximum consecutive positive profit per account. If we sort the input data by account, it is easy to represent the information we need to sum:

[image: accomodated the input data]

**Note**: After the sort operation the order within each account is preserved.

We aim to find the maximum consecutive positive profit within each account (highlighted by color).

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*. In cell `E2` you can put the following formula:

```
=LET(in,A2:C12, acc,TAKE(in,,1), prof,TAKE(in,,-1), sortIdx,{1,2},
 h,{"Account Number","Most Consecutive Profits #","Total Consecutive Profits $"},
 FUN, LAMBDA(x,case, SCAN(0,x, LAMBDA(ac,a, IF(a<0,0,ac+IF(case=1,1,a))))),
 REDUCE(h,UNIQUE(acc), LAMBDA(ac,a, LET(f,FILTER(prof,acc=a),
  VSTACK(ac,HSTACK(a,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(FUN(f,1),FUN(f,)),sortIdx,-1),1)))))))
```

**Note**: Since we use `SORT`, several sorting strategies can be defined. It is determined by the name `sortIdx`. The current `sortIdx` value, is first by consecutive count, then by profit. Therefore for equal count, then the profit is taken into consideration. If `sortIdx={2,1}` is the other way around.

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We use [VSTACK/REDUCE pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) to calculate the result for each unique account. The formula is built using names for *easy reading and composition*. It helps to debug the formula extracting partial results.

`FUN` is a user `LAMBDA` function, to do the cumulative sum or count, based on the input value `case`. When `case=1` it does the count, otherwise, a sum:

```
FUNC, LAMBDA(x,case, SCAN(0,x, LAMBDA(ac,a, IF(a<0,0,ac+IF(case=1,1,a)))))
```

For each unique account. It does the cumulative positive profit (`FUN(f,)`) and consecutive counts (`FUN(f,1)`) within each group via `FUN`. Each group is delimited by the count equal to `0`, i.e. when it has a negative profit within a given account.

For example, for the `2101822` account the cumulative calculation for each group is:

```
cnts  sum
3     1102.58
1     1000
```

and from here it takes the maximum according to the sorting criteria, i.e. `{3,1102.58}` which is part of the output of `REDUCE` for this iteration.

The output of each iteration of `REDUCE` will be:

```
VSTACK(ac,HSTACK(a,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(FUN(f,1),FUN(f,)),sortIdx,-1),1)))
```

It sorts, in descending order based on `sortIdx`. Taking the first element via `TAKE` is an easy way to find the maximum based on the sorting criteria.

Finally, it uses `HSTACK` to add the account number, and `VSTACK` to vertically concatenate each result of `REDUCE` accumulation procedure.

Since `SUM` function (used in `FUN`) ignores non-numbers, we can initialize the recursion with the header (`h`).

As @JvdV pointed out in the comment sections of previous answers. This approach works for the case replacing `1001` by `1`. Here would be the expected result:

```
2101822 3   102.58
656546  2   250
```

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya for your information, I didn't do it, I don't remember downvoting any answer in SO. I did it with the intention for you to review it, I thought maybe it was some typo in the final update, but it is difficult for me to find it because of the Greek letters you use. I don't know how to share an image in a comment, I will try to find out, but your solution is still giving me the wrong result. In my excel version

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't mind using some extra steps and helper columns you can achieve what you want. You've said *the records are in chronological order top to bottom*. **You need this field to be used**

Or you can add it manually and just make it consecutive numbers like I've done:

[image]

Next step is **sorting data by Account No and then by date**. Then you data will look like this:

[image]

Notice I've added 2 helper columns named `Consecutive steps` and `Profit cumulative`. These steps are critical or the formulas won't work!

Formula for `Consecutive steps`:

```
=IF(I1=I2;IF(K2>0;L1+1;0);IF(K2>0;1;0))
```

Formula for `Profit cumulative`:

```
=IF(I2=I1;IF(L2>0;M1+K2;0);IF(L2>0;K2;0))
```

Then using these 2 extra columns you can get your expected output:

[image]

Formula to get `Most Consecutive Profits #`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($I$2:$I$12=I23)*$L$2:$L$12))
```

Formula to get `Total Consecutive Profits $`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($I$2:$I$12=I23)*$M$2:$M$12))
```

Notice these last 2 formulas based on SUMPRODUCT can be replaced with MAXIFS if you got Excel 365

Comment: I like the idea but unfortunately you have fallen for a very understandable oversight. You can't assume the max profit equals the total profit that is made in the longest consecutive streak of profits (if that makes sense). To showcase this, change the `1001` to a `1`

Comment: And a small remark about `MAXIFS()`, it's available from Excel 2019 onwards =)

Comment: @JvdV Oh I see your point and you are right. In this dataset it works but with different values as you suggested it wouldn't