# Create dynamic tables in Excel with dynamic rows and columns based on the content of other sheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have an excel sheet - Balance.
This sheet has 4 columns - Name, Item, Quantity, Unit.
Name can have values like - Test1, Test2, Test 3.
Item can have values like - ABC, XYZ, PQR.
Quantity can have values like - 200, 300, 400.
Unit can have values like - Box, Piece, Packets.

In another tab - Vendor Balance, I would like to create dynamic tables.

Tables for every vendor - Column names would include Unit. Row names would be Item. And their values would be Quantities. I want dynamic tables so that rows and columns get added/deleted based on the records in the Balance tab. The vendors can keep getting added. Records for existing/new vendors can keep getting added, deleted or modified.
I would also like the other tables for other vendors to get adjusted accordingly.

The Vendor Balance sheet should have such small tables for all the vendors. They can be placed side by side - maybe 3 tables side by side and the other 3 below these 3 and so on.

A sample screenshot of the expected result is below-

Is this possible to do in excel? Also, the records will keep getting added in the Balance sheet. The tables should keep getting updated.
Additionally, I intend to transfer this sheet to google sheets, so I hope the answers will work on google sheets as well. Or if we have something directly for google sheets, that should be fine as well.

Thanks in advance. Please be nice, I am a beginner.

Balance Sheet example -

| Name | Item | Quantity | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test 1 | ABC | 50 | Piece |
| Test 2 | ABC | 120 | Packet |
| Test 1 | XYZ | 5 | Piece |
| Test 1 | PQR | 10 | Piece |
| Test 1 | ABC | 20 | Box |
| Test 1 | ABC | 30 | Packet |
| Test 1 | PQR | 35 | Box |
| Test 1 | PQR | 65 | Packet |
| Test 1 | XYZ | 100 | Box |
| Test 1 | XYZ | 200 | Packet |
| Test 2 | ABC | 130 | Piece |
| Test 2 | PQR | 25 | Piece |
| Test 2 | XYZ | 14 | Piece |
| Test 2 | PQR | 35 | Packet |
| Test 2 | XYZ | 20 | Packet |

Vendor Balance Sheet example -

[image]

Comment: Please do us a favor and replace your examples with markdown tables.

Comment: otherwise, what you want to do is called "unpivot table". This question has already been answered many times here, so search for this term and it is very likely you will find a solution that fits you.

Comment: Use this: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*. There is a way of doing it, but usually, it is a verbose approach. Put in `F2` the following formula:

```
=LET(in,A2:D16, names,TAKE(in,,1),
 UNPIVOT, LAMBDA(name,d, LET(item,TAKE(d,,1), itemUX,UNIQUE(item),
  unit,TAKE(d,,-1), unitUx,TOROW(UNIQUE(unit)),
  ma,TRANSPOSE(N(item = TOROW(itemUX))), mb,N(unit = unitUx) * INDEX(d,,2),
  VSTACK(HSTACK(name,unitUx), HSTACK(itemUX,MMULT(ma,mb))))),
 red,REDUCE("",UNIQUE(names), LAMBDA(ac,a, 
  HSTACK(ac,"",UNPIVOT(a,FILTER(DROP(in,,1),names = a))))),
 IFERROR(DROP(red,,2),""))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

**Note**: The order in the output is not the same, but the values are correct. It is not clear from the sample what order to use. The order shown is as it appears in the sample (output of `UNIQUE`), but it can be sorted differently wrapping the result with the `SORT` function. There is no  `Test 3` name in the input sample, therefore the output is different from the sample output provided.

It defines a user `LAMBDA` function `UNPIVOT` to unpivot the information for a given `name`. The input `d` represents a subset from `in` where the first column is the given `name`, removing the name column.

The totals are calculated using `MMULT` which returns per row the unique items and per column the unique units. The value in `i,j` position of the matrix, represents the total quantity for a given unique item `i` and unique unit `j`.

Each input of `MMULT` is a matrix. The total rows of `ma` are the unique items and the columns are all items. It is a matrix with `0`,`1` values, indicating where the unique item is present. In a similar way the matrix `mb`, but for units. The only difference is that when it is present, then instead of `1`, it has the corresponding quantity. Multiplying both matrices provides the expected totals.

Then it uses [REDUCE/HSTACK pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) to generate the output for each name in the expected output, leaving an empty column to separate the information for each name. `IFERROR` is used to remove the `#N/A` values of the output. `DROP` is used to remove the first two columns of the result. The first column represents the column related to the initial value of the accumulator (`ac`) and the second column is used to separate each group of information, which is not required for the first name information.

Translating the previous formula to Google Sheets, you can use the following:

```
=LET(in,A2:D16, names,INDEX(in,,1),
 UNPIVOT, LAMBDA(name,d, LET(item,INDEX(d,,1), itemUX,UNIQUE(item),
  unit,INDEX(d,,3), unitUx,TOROW(UNIQUE(unit)),
  ma, TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(N(item = TOROW(itemUX)))), 
  mb, ARRAYFORMULA(N(unit = unitUx)* INDEX(d,,2)),
  VSTACK(HSTACK(name, unitUx), HSTACK(itemUX, MMULT(ma,mb))))),
 red, REDUCE("", UNIQUE(names), LAMBDA(ac,a,
  HSTACK(ac,"",UNPIVOT(a, FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(in,{2,3,4}), names = a))))),
 IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(red,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(red)-2,1,3)),""))
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Can't thank you enough.
However, the formula mentions A2:D16. The records can keep getting added and it won't be 16 always. It could go until D2500 or more. Is there any way we can make this dynamic? 
Additionally, these tables are shown side by side. If we would have 100 vendors, it would show me 100 tables next to each other. This would make it difficult to navigate. Can we show 3-4 side by side and then the next 3-4 tables below them and then so on.
I am sorry, I should have mentioned the order of these vendors/tables - it would be great if they would be sorted alphabetically

Comment: @user8107531 Thanks for your feedback, please keep in mind the way to show appreciation here is by upvoting the answer. About the dynamic range, it is always inefficient. You have two possible solutions.  1) Define the range as the entire column, replace the `in` definition with: `rng,DROP(A:D,1), in,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(rng,1),COLUMNS(rng))`. 2) Define the input range `in` as an Excel Table, that can grow dynamically, you would need to drop the header.

Comment: About accommodating the output, my answer aligns with the requirement of your question (sample output), I would suggest accepting my answer if you don't receive a better answer and posting another question based on this one. I guess it is more verbose but doable.

Comment: My previous suggestion 1) to deal with a dynamic dataset assume there is no empty cell in the range of interest. If I were you I would use an Excel Table. This is the way to handle in Excel kind of scenario.